# Archive pages for posts based on their taxonomy?

Tags: archives, taxonomy

Is it possible to display archive pages of posts based on their taxonomies, and an archive page of a term in that taxonomy??

For example, i have a site about beauty products, and i write a product review as a post. I want to put it in the 'hair' category, and in the taxonomy 'shampoo', with the term 'dry'. I have managed to create an archive page for all posts within the 'hair' category, but i cant figure out how i then create a page to show all products that are in 'hair' AND with a taxonomy of 'shampoo'. I would also need a further page showing all products in 'hair' AND 'shampoo' AND 'dry'. ie. mysite/hair/shampoo/dry where hair is the category, shampoo is the taxonomy, and dry is the term.

Am i on the right track in thinking i need to create a taxonomy-shampoo.php page? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,
Patrick.

Comment: Interesting question, but it needs some clarification. Both `category` and your `shampoo` are taxonomies. If you want to view all posts with the `dry` tag in the `shampoo` taxonomy, you should get them at `mysite/shampoo/dry`, like you can see the category `hair` at `mysite/categories/hair` (with the original structure). But you want to add an extra format: `mysite/[category-slug]/[taxonomy-name]/[taxonomy-term-slug]`, to view all posts in one category *and* one term of your custom taxonomy. I think you need to add a new rewrite structure to support that.

Answer (score 2):

The [Template Hierarchy Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) is your friend.

- Archive page for category *hair*: `category-hair.php`
- Archive page for taxonomy *shampoo*: `taxonomy-shampoo.php`
- Archive page for taxonomy *shampoo* term *dry*: `taxonomy-shampoo-dry.php`

To display some cross-query between different taxonomies, such as *category* and a custom taxonomy, such as *hair*, you'll need to do a *custom query*, and display it on your own custom page template, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to display archive pages of posts based on their taxonomies,

Yes.

> and an archive page of a term in that taxonomy??

Yes, as that's exactly the way it's done IIRC.

In case you can't do that with what's in out-of-the box, you can always [do a custom query (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) in conjunction with overriding your theme either in the theme loader or by [registering something within the Permalink/URL space](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/issues-when-rewrite-rules-collide).

Answer (score 0):

Check it, WordPress supports templates for taxonomy archives, both for the taxonomy itself and its individual terms, out of the box: http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png

But unfortunately, I don't know how to make a taxonomy for a taxonomy (categories are simply a kind of taxonomy, a default kind). All taxonomies exist unto themselves, in separate permalink structures.

Looking at your example, I want to know, why not just make "shampoo" a sub-category of "hair?" Then you'd get your URL of `mysite/categories/hair/shampoo/dry`.