# A tool to analyze rewrite rules?

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, wpse-plugin

Is there a good tool to analyze my rewrite rules? I always get confused with the regexes and the parameter replacements.

*I have created something myself and will post it here so others can use it, but please feel free to add other tools!*

Comment: I don't understand the analyse part. For what should this be good for in concrete? just to read rewrite rules? that's the only plugin I'm aware of so far: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/askapaches-rewriterules-viewer/

Comment: @hakre: Analyze and debug, in case you want to add a new rewrite rule but don't understand why it is not working. My current version for example also checks whether the query vars are read by `WP::parse_request()`. It is part of a larger effort to understand and maybe even improve the documentation of the rewrite engine.

Comment: Denis named an interesting aspect here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/performance-of-my-permalink-structure/3437#3437 -- number of rules per post / page.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Well what a coincidence that you ask this, Jan! Just today I had time on a long train journey and decided to write a Rewrite Analyzer plugin, one that parses your rewrite rules and highlights the query variables. You can test URLs right there and see what query variables will be set.

[image: Display all rewrite rules and highlight captured URL parts and ignored query variables]

[image: Test URLs and see matching rules with the resulting query variables]

You can find it [in the plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), or just as *Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer* when search for new plugins in your administration screen.

Comment: Nice would be to have that as an addition to the debug bar :)

Comment: Is there an SVN the plugin can be pulled from?

Comment: Question, Jan: when something is crossed out in red, what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @Manny: Red query variables are not marked as public, so they will not be sent to the `$wp_query` object and you will have a hard time accessing them later.

Comment: Very useful!  Thanks!  I haven't totally [gotten things working](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26497/querystring-parameter-getting-lost-in-rewrite-rule), but it's been a huge help so far.

Comment: Too bad this is so outdated! I haven't even tried and went straight to an alternative, which is quite outdated itself (2 years without updates): https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/ - but apparently it worked on newest wordpress (4.3.1).

Comment: @Cawas: I think it might still work. It has been a while since I did some serious WordPress work, but the code is very backwards compatible.