# How can I make wp-pagenavi work on a custom query built upon a form submission?

Tags: custom-field, pagination, query, forms, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I've also posted this on the wordpress support forums, for scribu's wp-pagenavi plugin:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-pagenavi-custom-query-form-submit-part-2?replies=1

My situation:

I am using a form to create a custom query that displays posts from a custom post type archive matching a certain custom field (Eg: For "custom-post-type" show only posts that have the "custom-field" value selected from the form). I know, it's called filtering :P

My custom post type archive looks like this:

`www.example.com/custom-post-type-archive`

(note that I use the "post name" permalink setting)

Upon form submission, the new url is this:

`www.example.com/custom-post-type-archive?key=value`

The custom query is set to show only posts with *value* of *key* custom field:

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
$paged = get_query_var('page');
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
        'meta_key' => 'key',
        'meta_value' => $value,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

After the loop I have:

```
wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $my_query));
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The query works, I get the right results. But I have problems getting pagination to work. When I go to the next page, I get this url:

`www.example.com/custom-post-type-archive/page/2?key=value`

but pagination still shows like I'm on the first page and the results are the same.

If I manually enter:

`www.example.com/custom-post-type-archive?key=value&page=2`

I get the right results (from page 2), but the all navigation links are the same as the url I manually entered above.

Please help (hints, resources, anything).

Thx,
Radu

Comment: I also have similar problem, did you found the solution yet? Can you share it here?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @p.a, @tc.k, I solved the problem using the `paged` parameter (instead of `page`) in `get_query_var` and implementing ajax pagination just as @swtshweta pointed out. I think it would have worked even without ajax.

Comment: Yep, the solution is definitely using `paged` instead of `page` as a parameter (I am using WP 3.3.2 and WP-pagenavi 2.82). Works without Ajax pagination, although using that technique looks awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try implementing ajax based pagination for wp-pagenavi plugin(see http://wordpressapi.com/2011/05/16/add-ajax-pagination-in-wordpress-blog/ for reference ). I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Because this comes up in search, I'd like to point out that WP Page Navi ( as of version 2.74 ) now supports custom queries.

The [WP_Pagenavi FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/faq/) links to the following article to explain [how to use the Pagenavi plugin with a secondary query](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html) by passing the `wp_pagenavi()` function a query parameter.

From the tutorial:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    // more stuff here
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );

wp_reset_postdata();    // avoid errors further down the page
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem has been already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13216165/1801379

You ca also get some idea from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4131/23290

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions I found (note I'm using WP 3.3.2 and WP-Pagenavi 2.82):

**Solution 1:**  Using `paged` instead of `page` as a `get_query_var` parameter.

**Solution 2** Using ajax based navigation, just as in the article swtshweta pointed out.
(using Ajax, pagination works properly even with the `page` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the answer proposed does not show anything on my browser. I have the latest WP and latest Chrome browser.
Thanks anyway.

Although wp_pagenavi appears correctly, and the links show /page2/, /page3/ and so on, and I have added the $paged or $page attribute to my wp_query, always the first page appears.

Comment: are you calling the `wp_pagenavi` function correctly: `wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $your_custom_query));` ?

Comment: I tried both but none worked.
I realised that the variable $paged variable is always submitted as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Radu,
The following solution worked for me:
I modified a standard paging code, and made it submit "&page=xxx" and catched $page as form submission variable. It now works perfect.

Notice the last line, this is where modifications happened.

```
global $paged;
$paged = ($_GET["page"]) ? ($_GET["page"]) : 1; //this is where I catch the requested page

function pagenavi( $found_posts, $p = 2 ) { // pages will be show before and after current page
  if ( is_singular() ) return; // don't show in single page
  global $paged;
  $max_page =  intval($found_posts / 10) + 1;
  echo('max_page=' . $max_page);
  if ( $max_page == 1 ) return; // don't show when only one page
  if ( empty( $paged ) ) $paged = 1;
  echo '<span class="pages">Page: ' . $paged . ' of ' . $max_page . ' <BR></span> '; // pages
  if ( $paged > $p + 1 ) p_link( 1, 'First' );
  if ( $paged > $p + 2 ) echo '... ';
  for( $i = $paged - $p; $i <= $paged + $p; $i++ ) { // Middle pages
    if ( $i > 0 && $i <= $max_page ) $i == $paged ? print "<span class='page-numbers current'>{$i}</span> " : p_link( $i );
  }
  if ( $paged < $max_page - $p - 1 ) echo '... ';
  if ( $paged < $max_page - $p ) p_link( $max_page, 'Last' );
}
 function p_link( $i, $title = '' ) {
  if ( $title == '' ) $title = "Page {$i}";
  echo "<a class='page-numbers' href='", esc_html( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&page=' .$i ), "' title='{$title}'>{$i}</a> ";
```

}

Comment: <<To stachexchange admins>> please consider my answer as response to my bounty faq. The solutions offered by members were worthwile but did not work for me, since the proposed solution $paged = get_query_var('page'); was always EMPTY for my system. Thanks.