# Custom query form submission pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, forms, session

There is a question very similar to mine, which can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57189/how-can-i-make-wp-pagenavi-work-on-a-custom-query-built-upon-a-form-submission). The difference with my question is: my search form is on several pages (`page.php` and `single.php`) and I don't use wp-pagenavi. I've tried the suggested solutions posted there but they didn't work.

**What is working**

- The query displays the right results
- The query displays the right results after form submission
- Pagination shows with the correct links (ie example.com/overview/?paged=2 and example.com/city/boston/?paged=2)
- Pagination with the same settings works on search.php

**What is not working:** if I submit the form and click on any page but page 1 the URL does become example.com/overview/?paged=2 or example.com/city/boston/?paged=2 but no results are displayed.

**Updated after the accepted answer:**
Please read the notes in the code to see how the problem was solved.

**--- Below here the setup of my code**

On **page.php**

```
if(is_page('overview')) {
    get_template_part('templates/overview', 'main');
}
```

On **single.php** (include the same file)

```
if(is_singular('cities')) {
    get_template_part('templates/overview', 'main');
}
```

On **overview-main.php**

```
include_once 'overview-search-input.php'; 
include_once 'overview-sidebar.php';
```

On **overview-search-input.php (changed after UPDATE 3, original code below here)**

```
   if(!empty($_GET['period'])) {
        $period = $_GET['period'];
   }
   else {
        $period = 'upcoming'; // Set to upcoming if nothing is selected
   }

   $query = search_v1($period, $paged); // Passing the $paged parameter in the query

   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // The $paged parameter
```

On **overview-sidebar.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="get"> 
<select name="period" placeholder="Select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="all"></option>
  <option value="upcoming"></option>
</select>
</form>
```

in the function **search_v1**:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 20,
        'paged'             => $paged, // This was passed into the function
        'meta_query'        => array($meta_query), // This is generated based on the $period input and it's working (tested)
        'meta_key'          => 'date_from',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
    );

    return new WP_Query($args);
```

Then on **overview-main.php**

```
   if($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
      // Do stuff
    endwhile;

    create_pagination($query);

    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

And in the function **create_pagination**:

```
$query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

$args = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => false,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>',
    'next_text' => '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>',
    'type' => 'list'
);

return paginate_links($args);
```

**The problem was:** Since both pagination functions work and display the correct pagination links I assume that's not the problem. I think it lies in the custom query (since this pagination works on search.php when the results are generated once and not altered by form input).

**The problem was solved:** by using the 'paged' parameter and passing it into the query

Comment: If you're sending POST data to a page to manipulate the query, that data isn't persisted across subsequent page loads, because you're not POSTing that data again.

Comment: That explains. Can you point me in the right direction of how to post the data again?

Comment: you don't need sessions. change your form to submit via get instead of post, then you can just append any existing form get vars onto your pagination links.

Comment: This question has been solved - reward the bounty to @G.M. please! :)

Comment: Thanks Eric. This was my first time putting a bounty on a question and I thought it would be granted by accepting the answer. I've rewarded it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things that should be changed in your code:

1. Please no not use `$_SESSION` stuff. So do not add session_start anywhere. You can pass the current state via the query string, using `method="get"` in your form.
2. For a better flow, you can pass the current page to `search_v1` function as argument, in this way you are sure will be not errors
3. When you have to access [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array, instead of accessing directly is recomned to use [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)
4. in the `overview-search-input.php` file, last line is `$query = search_v1($_SESSION['period']);` that is completely useless
5. I think is useful in the form select the period option of the current showed posts, e.g. when you are viewing posts for period 'upcoming', in the form should be selected the option 'upcoming'.

Applying this changes:

- `page.php` and `single.php` and stay unchanged.
- remove `session_start();` from where you have added

Then

#### `overview-search-input.php`

```
<?php
$period = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'period', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( empty($period ) ) $period  = 'upcoming';
if ( empty($paged) ) $paged = 1;
```

---

#### `overview-sidebar.php`

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="get">
<select name="period" placeholder="Select">
  <option <?php selected('', $period) ?>></option>
  <option <?php selected('all', $period) ?>>all</option>
  <option <?php selected('upcoming', $period) ?>>upcoming</option>
</select>
</form>
```

---

#### `overview-main.php`

```
include_once 'overview-search-input.php';
include_once 'overview-sidebar.php';

$query = search_v1( $period, $paged );

if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  // Do stuff
endwhile;

echo create_pagination( $query, $period );

wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

---

Finally the 2 functions, `search_v1` and `create_pagination`:

```
function search_v1( $period = 'upcoming', $paged = 1 ) {
  if ( empty($paged) ) $paged = 1;
  $meta_query = array(
    // create your meta query here
  );
  $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_query'        => array($meta_query),
    'meta_key'          => 'date_from',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
  );
  return new WP_Query( $args );
}


function create_pagination( $query, $period = 'upcoming' ) {
  $current = isset($query->query_vars['paged']) ? $query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
  $args = array(
    'base' => get_permalink() . '%_%',
    'format' => '?paged=%#%&period=' . $period,
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => ($current > 0) ? $current : 1,
    'show_all' => false,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>',
    'next_text' => '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>',
    'type' => 'list'
  );
  return paginate_links($args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My full code is way more complex and I did some alterations on yours, but this was definitely the answer that made it work. I'll update my question to show the working code. But it leaves me with one point of confusion; what's the deal with `'paged'` vs `'page'` in the query arguments? Because @Subharanjan suggested `'page'` is used for custom queries, but I'm now using `'paged'` and everyting works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Can you use this and check.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Also this

```
$query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
```

to

```
$query->query_vars['page'] > 1 ? $current = $query->query_vars['page'] : $current = 1;
```

**Note:** As you are using custom page templates, "paged" doesn't work there.

Comment: If I do that I get the error `Notice: Undefined index: page`. If I change the `'paged'` parameter to `'page'` in the `$args` of `$query` the problem is the same as described.

Comment: PS I've also changed `paged` to `page` in @add_query_arg and `paged` to `page` in '?paged=%#%` of to no avail.