# Custom rewrite rules for pages

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to get WordPress to recognize a URL structure like this:

```
example.com/parent/page/{id}/{first_name}/{last_name}
```

The basic ideea is that I need to access the `id`, `first_name` and `last_name` in my page and they have to come via the URL. So I have to put rules like:

```
(/some_page/child_page/)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) =>
index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]&fname=$matches[3]&lname=$matches[4]
```

for every page, by using the `page_rewrite_rules` filter.

The question is: How to I get the "pagename" for every page? The `/some_page/child_page/` part. I can get the `post_name` but then I miss the parent, grandfather page.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern WordPress uses to recognize pages is `(.+?)`, which will match anything, but is not *greedy*, so it allows you to put something at the end. The following code works for me in WordPress 3.0.1: it places the extra pattern at the second-to-last place of the list, because the final pattern is so generic it will match every URL:

```
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'wpse7243_page_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse7243_page_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
    // The most generic page rewrite rule is at end of the array
    // We place our rule one before that
    end( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_pattern = key( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_replacement = array_pop( $rewrite_rules );
    $rewrite_rules +=  array(
        '(.+?)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]&fname=$matches[3]&lname=$matches[4]',
        $last_pattern => $last_replacement,
    );
    return $rewrite_rules;
}
```

Be aware that pages, like any post, can also be split into multiple *pages* with the `<!--nextpage-->` snippet, and the normal URL for that is `/pagename/2/`, which might be confusing when you also have `/pagename/3/jan/fabry/` where the `3` is an ID. You can change the pattern to include an optional page number at the end, so this can become `/pagename/3/jan/fabry/2/` where the final `2` is the page number, and the first `3` is the ID.

If you are changing the rewrite rules I recommend [my rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) (soon in the repository, [but get the current version via Dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7057637/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.zip)), it helps you debug these things.