# Fixing custom rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting

I am following the [WP Example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples). I know my rewrite rule is being added into wordpress, so I just need to fix the actual rule. So here is my current code:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','mcs_TextbookRewriteRules');
add_filter('query_vars','mcs_insertTextbookQueryVars');

// Adding a new rule
function mcs_TextbookRewriteRules($rules) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['textbook/(cantonese|mandarin)/([C|M]K?[0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=textbook/$matches[1]/?cls=$matches[2]&ch=$matches[3]';
    //$newrules['textbook/(cantonese|mandarin)/([C|M]K?[0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$'] = 'textbook/$matches[1]/index.php?cls=$matches[2]&ch=$matches[3]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
    function mcs_insertTextbookQueryVars($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'cls');
    array_push($vars, 'ch');
    return $vars;
}
```

I want to map `http://localhost/wordpress/textbook/cantonese/CK1/6` to `http://localhost/wordpress/textbook/cantonese/?cls=CK1&ch=6`

Comment: What you want to map to will not work because it's an intermediate representation. You need to fully map to query parameters off of `'index.php'`. Does `'textbook'` represent a custom post type, or is it a page with `'cantonese'` and `'mandarin'` represent a term in a custom taxonomy or a category or a tag? Your regular express references `'C'` and  `'M'` but your example uses `'CK'`; please clarify. We need a lot more details about your use-case and your data.

Comment: @Mike: If there are pages at `textbook/cantonese/` and `textbook/mandarin/`, the `pagename` parameter can work.

Comment: @Mike - Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed it in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a second `?` in your query variables (before the `cls` query variable), probably from experimenting with the commented-out form, I think you want to use `&` there.

Your `query_vars` hook currently adds the `id` variable, but you use `cls` and `ch` in your rewrite rule, so this will not have an effect.

If you are changing the rewrite rules I recommend [my rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) (soon in the repository, [but get the current version via Dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7057637/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.zip)), it helps you debug these things.

Comment: Your plugin is pure awesome :). I use it alot.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out in the query_vars, I did not know what it was for. I updated the code and is reflected above. Now `textbook/cantonese/CK1/6` is displaying `textbook/cantonese/`. I had set a `if(isset($_GET['cls'])){ echo $_GET['cls']; }`. Is there a certain way to call the variable that I am missing?

Comment: I figured it out that I need to call it using `get_query_var()`. Thank you for all your help.