# How to change permalinks to show categoryname/post-name?

Tags: permalinks

I've placed the string below into my custom permalinks input but it does not appear to have any effect...

> /%category%/%postname%/

I'm trying to insure that my post links are in the form of /category-name/post-name

Comment: What is not working? Did you have a 404 error ? mod_rewrite is enabled in your server ?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is working (ie, I can change permalinks to post-title.html, just not categoryname/post-title.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As in, what is your desired URL format?

Comment: site.com/category-slug/post-slug

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your rules with my rewrite analyzer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a link to the site in question, it's hard to understand the exact problem. However, if the issue is the actual word "category" is being includes (i.e. example.com/category/category-name/post-name) then I would use this plugin (it's one I use on almost every site)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Answer (score 0):

It could be 3rd party wordpress theme conflict. Temporarily enable the **default** WP theme and test.

Also note:

> For performance reasons, it is not a
>   good idea to start your permalink
>   structure with the category, tag,
>   author, or postname fields. The reason
>   is that these are text fields, and
>   using them at the beginning of your
>   permalink structure it takes more time
>   for WordPress to distinguish your Post
>   URLs from Page URLs (which always use
>   the text "page slug" as the URL), and
>   to compensate, WordPress stores a lot
>   of extra information in its database
>   (so much that sites with lots of Pages
>   have experienced difficulties). So, it
>   is best to have at least two path
>   segments in your post's permalink
>   structure such as /%year%/%postname%/
>   or even /posts/%postname%/.

Source: [Wordpress.org Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: This has been debated quite a bit. If you have a lot of posts / pages (in the thousands) then you can see a hit on the performance. Otherwise, I've never seen it make a difference one way or the other.