# Regex problem in an add_rewrite_rule

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, url-rewriting, archives

I'm working on a category page for a custom post type called articles in WP 3.1, and I'm having some trouble with extracting the page number.

The url: `/articles/category/background/`

Currently, what works for me, from my `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse7379_init' );
function wpse7379_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'articles/category/([^/]+)(/page/([0-9]+))/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=articles&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

This internally rewrites the url to: 
`/index.php?post_type=articles&category_name=background`

I'm trying to make the pagination work by expanding the rewrite rule, but it's not working for me.

The pagination works as follows: `/articles/category/background/page/2/`

New rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'articles/category/([^/]+)(/page/([0-9]+))/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=articles&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

This should rewrite the url to:
`/index.php?post_type=articles&category_name=background&paged=2`

I'm using a query with args on my `archive-articles.php` page, but just a regular loop on the `categories.php` page, where the posts are displayed.

When I try `/index.php?post_type=articles&category_name=background&paged=2` it works, but the url that gets rewritten doesn't. Its just displaying the first page, no matter what I enter as pagenumber.

Does anyone know how to fix this? **I think I'm looking for a proper regex, I kinda suck at regexes, so I guess thats the problem.**

Comment: Are you using a custom query or passing args to query_posts?

Comment: Added some clarification. I'm using a normal loop on the categories.php page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see three issues in your rewrite rule.

- The page number is the *third*, not the second capture group. You count each opening `(`, so the first is the category name, the second is `/page/[0-9]+`, and the third is only the `[0-9]+` you need. So change the `paged` parameter to `$matches[3]`.
- The page part can be optional, so you need to add a `?` at the end (this is the reason we put it in a group).
- The categories can be hierarchical, like `/fruit/banana/`. For this reason, you should not match them with `[^/]+` (any character except a slash), but `.+?` (any character, but *non greedy*, so that the rest of the regex can still match).

Together, this results in the following rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'articles/category/(.+?)(/page/([0-9]+))?/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=articles&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
```

If you don't use it already, I recommend you debug your rules with my [rewrite analyzer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608). You can test them live and see what the query values will be.

Comment: That works, awesome! I really can't thank you enough for both the solution and the explanation, simply amazing :)