# Custom Post Types: pretty search URLs and has_archive

Tags: custom-post-types, search, rewrite-rules

This is a question based on the comments from the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44044/6344).

I'm using the following code to create a couple of different search boxes for my website:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/glossary/' ); ?>" method="get">
    <p style="font-size:12px;">SEARCH<strong class="dkblue">GLOSSARY</strong></p>
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" class="glossary_submit" />
</form>

<form id="profilesearch" action="<?php echo home_url( '/species/' ); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" size="50" class="default-value" value="SEARCH" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" class="profilesearch_submit" />
    <!-- <p class="tinysearch"><a href="/dev/advanced-search/">ADVANCED SEARCH</a></p> -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="showthumbnails" id="showthumbnails" class="checkbox" <?php if ($_POST["showthumbnails"] == "on") { echo 'checked="checked" '; } ?>/><label for="showthumbnails">HIDE THUMBNAILS</label>
</form>
```

My `glossary` CPT has the following creation `$args`:

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => true,    
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => false,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'menu_position' => 40,
  'menu_icon' => $this->plugin_url . 'images/glossary.png',
  'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes')
);
```

And my `species` CPT has these:

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => true,
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'menu_icon' => $this->plugin_url . 'images/fish20.png',
  'supports' => array('author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments','revisions')
);
```

Currently, when I submit a search from the glossary form, the URL changes to: `/glossary/?s=term`. When I submit a search from the species form, the URL changes to: `/search/term`.

The glossary URL does what it's meant to do - searches for `glossary` CPT types only. The species URL however simply searches for everything.

**If I change `has_archive` to `false`, the searches work as per the above `glossary`. If I change it to `true`, the searches work as per the above `species`.**

What I want both to do is this: change URL to `/search/cpt-slug/term`, i.e. `/search/species/bettas` and search for only posts with that CPT.

Have I done something wrong with my `$args`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most unfortunate, while my original solution was elegant I did not foresee this complication, and I apologise for the inconvenience.

So, I provide an alternative solution.

**Firstly to get your fancy search query:**

Your markup will need to change, but this will intercept the URLs and rewrite them correctly internally, it is similar to the other answer but prettier, faster, easier to read, and in a single function

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'search/(.+)/(.+)'      =>  'index.php?post_type='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&s=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

Thus `example.com/search/post/bannana` will search all posts of type 'post' for bannana.

If you would prefer instead not to 'search' but to instead show a term, all you need to do is modify the query variables in the rewrite rule.

You can use the monkeyman rewrite rules analyser plugin to help you, by putting in URLs and being shown which rewrite rule handles it and the priority/order of said rules

**BUT**

However, you will not be able to use the elegant html markup to use these URLs, it will not play nicely, you will need to modify where the forms is submitted to which means while this might sound like a marvellous idea, in practice the implementation means you will need at least 1 redirect for a searchbox to work with these URLs, which is not ideal at all.

**For your species search problem**

Also modify your species registration to be more specific/accurate:

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => false, // lets not guess what this will be, lets be authorative
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => true,
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'menu_icon' => $this->plugin_url . 'images/fish20.png',
  'supports' => array('author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments','revisions')
);
```

But, while this *might* fix it, I suspect not. Rereading your question, I see it rewrites to /search/term, but WordPress does not do this by default. I suspect you have code somewhere else that rewrites search terms into a prettier version for general post searches, but this is interfering, be it because of the order of where its added in the code or something else.

Since I can't see your entire codebase, and I'm not sure what this search code prettification looks like, I can't help you any further than to point you in its directions ( and to conditionally rewrite if post_type is not set rather than always).

**edit: give this a try:**

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'species/(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'      =>  'index.php?post_type=species&species='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&page='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Cheers Tom, I'll have a go at this tonight :)

Comment: Thanks for this Tom. Your rewrite rule is working, but the searches still aren't. My species search ends up with this URL: `/search/species/?s=test` and my glossary `/glossary/?s=test`. Any ideas? I haven't changed the markup, still using this format: `<form id="profilesearch" action="<?php echo home_url( '/species/' ); ?>" method="get">`.

Comment: But if you go directly to the expected URL it works no? hmmm in that case you need to make sure it goes to the correct location but I'm not sure how you would account for that, which means that rewrite rules on their own aren't enough.

Comment: Can you install the monkeyman rewrite analyser plugin and put in the expected URL and see what rules are activated?

Comment: Also, add exclude_from_search => false, as it may be autogenerating the value based on has_archive and public

Comment: I've updated my answer, I have questions that need answering and I realise a problem I had in my reasoning that means neither rewrite rule actually fixes your problem, just your second request

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your responses! If I go to `/search/species/test`, the correct search results appear (only species profiles containing %test%). The rewrite rules can be found here: http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/RewriteRules.png. Unfortunately the changes to the `$args` didn't make any difference.

Comment: No I mean if my original answer had worked then you would get the url /species/?s=term but you do not. If you put that URL into the rewrite analyser, what do you get?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I've updated my image - check the same URL.

Comment: I've modified my answer, try the code at the very end and see what it does to the rewrite rules

Comment: Apologies for the delay Tom - working on so many things at once. I've updated my image again.

Comment: Can you show me what glossary/?s=test gives you? You could then use that as a basis to create a new rewrite rule for the species

Comment: http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/RewriteRules2.png <= glossary. I have to be honest Tom, I'm not sure what we're working on here - I have no experience of rewrite rules. What steps will I need to take from here?

Comment: aha thanks, I've updated the last codeblock in the question, could you give that a try and see if everything is corrected?

Comment: I still suspect there's code somewhere else interfering, but I cant go much further than this without seeing your code in more detail which isn't really appropriate here

Comment: Yeah - appreciate that. I'm just trying to understand what we're actually doing here, so I can work on it myself. I've added the code you gave me, but I can't see that anything has changed. I guess the question for me is twofold now. Firstly, if I go to `/species/?s=test`, it's still re-directing just to `search` and displaying all post types. Secondly, how can I get my `<input>` search forms to re-direct to `/glossary/search/term`?

Comment: I was trying to get the rewrite rule being used for glossary and then recreate a version for species. I shall have a think though if there's any way of me seeing your themes code in full

Comment: What do you need? I have around 41 PHP files alone in my theme. Do you just need the plugin file and the functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to work on permalinks. I don't have time at the moment but you can find some info here: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add

Here's some code to get you started, it's based on another [article that was taken down](http://www.johnpbloch.com/2010/08/custom-post-types-and-better-permalinks/), I can't guarantee it will work.

```
add_filter('wp_loaded','bfr_add_permastruct');
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','bfr_add_permalink_rule');

function bfr_add_permastruct(){
    add_permastruct('ctp_search', 'search/%post-type%/%postname%');

  //Remember to flush_rules() when for the first time 
  //$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Adding a new rule
function bfr_add_permalink_rule($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]name=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Comment: Nice, though the issue here si that it will add the rule everytime wordpress runs, not just when the rewrite rules are generated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tom, I've worked out what my problem was...!

I found this little nugget in my `functions.php`. Must've been from literally a year ago as I don't even remember putting it in!

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {

    if ( is_search() and false === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/search/' . str_replace( ' ', '+', str_replace( '%20', '+', get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        exit();
    }

}
```

This was causing my /species/search/ to fail. Replacing it with this has done the trick:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {

    if ( is_search() and false === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/' ) ) {
        if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/species/' ) )
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/species/search/' . str_replace( ' ', '+', str_replace( '%20', '+', get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        else if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/glossary' ) )
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/glossary/search/' . str_replace( ' ', '+', str_replace( '%20', '+', get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        else
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/search/' . str_replace( ' ', '+', str_replace( '%20', '+', get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );

        exit();
    }

}
```

Next up, I had to change `has_archive` to `true` on my `glossary` CPT.

Finally, I used Tom's rewrite rules and some knowledge from [this excellent post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9255/6344) to get my pretty URLs working:

```
/* --- rewrite rules for searches...*/
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $species = array(
        '(species|glossary)/search/(.+?)(/page/([0-9]+))?/?$'      =>  'index.php?post_type='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&s='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&paged='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(4)
    );  

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $species + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

**I now have working pretty URLs on my custom post type searches, AND pagination: `/species/search/term`, `/species/search/term/page/2/` and `/glossary/search/term`, etc. all work correctly.**

Thanks Tom, credit goes to you!

Comment: yay! ^_^ Glad you got everything working, and you improved on my code too!