# Custom post type permalinks giving 404s

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I'm having trouble setting up permalinks for a custom post type.
Below is the code from my init function:

```
register_post_type('topic',
  array(
   ...
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => false,
   ...
  ));

if(get_option('permalink_structure')!= ''):
  global $wp_rewrite;

  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%topic%', '(.+?)', 'topic=');
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('topic', '%forum%/%topic%/', false, EP_PERMALINK);
endif;
```

Basically I'm trying to set up permalinks my own way because I want to append a custom taxonomy term before the post title.

Instead of: `topic/whatever`

use: `general-forum/sub-forum/whatever`

This is the function that changes the link, which seems to work ok:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'topic_link', 10, 4);
function topic_link($link, $post){
  if($post->post_type != 'topic') return $link;
  global $wp_post_types;
  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'forum');
  if(!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)):
    usort($terms, '_usort_terms_by_id');
    $forums = $terms[0]->slug;
    if(!empty($terms[0]->parent)):
      $parent_item = $terms[0]->parent;
      while(!empty($parent_item)):
        $parent = get_term($parent_item, 'forum');
        if(!is_wp_error($parent) && !empty($parent))
        $forums = $parent->slug.'/'.$forums;
        $parent_item = empty($parent->parent) ? false : $parent->parent;
      endwhile;
    endif;
  endif;
  return str_replace('%forum%', $forums, $link);
}
```

So the modified URL is displayed fine, the only problem is that I get a 404 error :)
What am I doing wrong in my init code?

**LE:** the 'forum' taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
  'forum',
    array('topic', 'reply'),
    array(
      'public' => true,
      'name' => _a('Forums'),
      'singular_name' => _a('Forum'),
      'show_ui' => true,
      //'show_tagcloud' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,

      'labels' => array(
        'name' => _a('Forums'),
        'singular_name' => _a('Forum'),
        'search_items' => _a('Search Forums'),
        'popular_items' => _a('Popular Forums'),
        'all_items' => _a('All Forums'),
        'parent_item' => _a('Parent Forum'),
        'parent_item_colon' => _a('Parent Forum:'),
        'edit_item' => _a('Edit Forum'),
        'update_item' => _a('Update Forum'),
        'add_new_item' => _a('Add New Forum'),
        'new_item_name' => _a('New Forum Name'),
      ),
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'forums', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true),
      //'update_count_callback' => 'my_custom_count_callback',
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My plugin Custom Post Permalinks does this sort of thing for you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks

If you'd rather use your own solution, I'll need a bit more information, such as the registration code for the forums taxonomy.

Just guessing, I'm thinking the regex for a forum looks identical to the regex for a topic to the rewrite engine.

### EDIT

Looking at your code, it looks like you're using 3.1. The `$args['rewrite']['hierarchical']` bit for taxonomies wasn't in 3.0. Basically, what that argument does is changes the regular expression for the `%forum%` tag from `([^/])` to `(.+?)`. This means that WordPress' rewrite engine gets a match for this regular expression first:

```
 @/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$
```

Which, for something like `/generic-forum/specific-forum/specific-topic`, will parse to this:

```
index.php?forum=generic-forum&topic=specific-forum/specific-topic
```

To test if this is really what's causing the 404, change the taxonomy's rewrite args so that `['rewrite']['hierarchical']` is either not set or set to false, flush the rewrite rules, and modify your topic link function not to add parents to the link; Then test to see if the new links work.

If this is the cause of the problems, there are a couple of ways to fix this. The easiest would be to add a bit of plain text to the permastruct, like this: `%forum%/topic/%topic%`. That would give you links like this: `/general-forum/sub-forum/topic/whatever`. Another way would be to add another rewrite tag like this:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%post_type_topic%', '(topic)', 'post_type=' );
```

then change the permastruct to '%forum%/%post_type_topic%/%topic%'.

Comment: Added the forum reg. tax code... Actually my code is based on your plugin :) I prefer not to use the plugin, as I don't need all the extra functionality...

Comment: Wonderful. Updated my answer with more accurate information on how to solve the problem. I should also note that the solutions at the bottom will work with hierarchical rewrite structures.

Comment: thanks, appending `topic` before `/%topic%` fixed it

Comment: now I see that I'm getting 404 errors when viewing single post pages; the same happens if I use your plugin (and using `/%forum%/topic/%topic%/` as permalink)

Comment: What is your permalink structure for your posts?

Comment: day and name is checked: `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

Comment: same happens when viewing a single page, or author archives. might be others too...

Comment: Yeah, the `%forum%` regex looks like `'@(.+?)/?$@'`. That means WP thinks EVERYTHING (except a topic) is a forum.

Comment: The way to avoid this is to anchor your custom permastruct with a non-variable regex (I usually use the post-type. E.g. `'forum/%forum%/topic/%topic%'`).

Comment: it works, but is there a way I can avoid all these extra prefixes?