# Permalinks in Custom Post types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Is it possible for a custom post type to have a permalink as `domain.com/custom-slug/` instead of `domain.com/custom/custom-slug/`?

I can't seem to achieve it. `rewrite` argument while registering it either defaults to the latter one or a custom one by using `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blah-blah' )`

Comment: by "custom-slug" you mean the post's slug?

Comment: @Bainternet exactly, I want it to be like how a WP page is

Comment: @Ashfame, were you able to get this figured out? I'm trying to accomplish the same myself now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**my answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-a-custom-hierarchical-taxonomy-permalink/10162#10162) to the following question. You can modify my `parse_request()` to get what you need:

- [*"Remove taxonomy slug from a custom hierarchical taxonomy permalink"*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-a-custom-hierarchical-taxonomy-permalink/).

And you can read the following to see why what you want can cause issues in WordPress and requires a complex solution:

- [*"Category in Permalinks Considered Harmful"*](http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/)

### UPDATE

Based on the comment I decided to go ahead and implement this as the next revision of the plugin. It's really only tested for the use-case for this question and the one from [the prior referenced question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-a-custom-hierarchical-taxonomy-permalink/10162#10162). Over time I plan to implement it for all potential use-cases, as questions or clients occur to drive the demand.

Here is the code you'd place in your theme's functions.php file to set it up for the post_type `'custom'`:

```
add_action('init','init_url_routes');
function init_url_routes() {
  $post_type = 'custom'; // Change this to your actual post_type name
  register_url_route(array('post_type'=>$post_type));
}
```

And here is the plugin which you can place in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/`:

```
<?php
/*
Filename: wp-extended.php
Plugin Name: WP Extended for Taxonomy URL Routes
Author: Mike Schinkel
Version: 0.2
*/
function register_url_route($args=array()) {
  WP_Extended::register_url_route($args);
}
class WP_Extended extends WP {
  static $root = array();
  static function on_load() {
    add_action('setup_theme',array(__CLASS__,'setup_theme'));
  }
  static function register_url_route($args) {
    if (isset($args['taxonomy']))
      self::$root['taxonomy'][$args['taxonomy']] = get_taxonomy($args['taxonomy']);
    if (isset($args['post_type']))
      self::$root['posts'][$args['post_type']] = get_post_type_object($args['post_type']);
  }
  static function setup_theme() { // Setup theme is 1st code run after WP is created.
    global $wp;
    $wp = new WP_Extended();  // Replace the global $wp
  }
  function parse_request($extra_query_vars = '') {
    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $domain = str_replace('.','\.',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    $root_path = preg_replace("#^https?://{$domain}(/.*)$#",'$1',WP_SITEURL);
    if (substr($path,0,strlen($root_path))==$root_path)
      $path = substr($path,strlen($root_path));
    list($path) = explode('?',$path);
    $path_segments = explode('/',trim($path,'/'));
    // This does not handle ordering priority of type to match yet
    $matched = $this->parse_post_type_request($path_segments);
    if (!$matched)
      $matched = $this->parse_taxonomy_request($path_segments);
    if ($matched) {
      // This is hamfisted but necessary in some cases.
      // TODO: Look into ways to have more finesse with this.
      remove_action('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
    } else {
      parent::parse_request($extra_query_vars); // Delegate to WP class
    }
  }
  function parse_post_type_request($path_segments) {
    // This does not handle heirarchical pages yet
    $post_id = false;
    global $wpdb;
    $sql =<<<SQL
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE 1=1
  AND post_status='publish'
  AND post_type='%s'
  AND post_name='%s'
SQL;
    if (is_array(self::$root['posts'])) {
      foreach(self::$root['posts'] as $post_type => $post_type_object) {
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_type,$path_segments[0]);
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
        if ($post_id) {
          $this->query_vars[($post_type=='page' ? 'page_id' : 'p')] = $post_id;
          unset($path_segments[0]);  // Remove from future consideration
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return ($post_id);
  }
  function parse_taxonomy_request($path_segments) {
    $taxonomy_term = array();
    $parent_id = 0;
    if (is_array(self::$root['taxonomy'])) {
      foreach(self::$root['taxonomy'] as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy) {
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy_slug);
        foreach($path_segments as $segment_index => $path_segment) {
          foreach($terms as $term_index => $term) {
            if ($term->slug==$path_segment) {
              if ($term->parent!=$parent_id) { // Make sure we test parents
                $taxonomy_term = array();
              } else {
                $parent_id = $term->term_id; // Capture parent ID for verification
                $taxonomy_term[] = $term->slug; // Collect slug as path segment
                unset($terms[$term_index]); // No need to scan it again
              }
              unset($path_segments[$segment_index]);  // Remove from future consideration
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (count($taxonomy_term))
          break;
      }
      if (count($taxonomy_term)) {
        $path = implode('/',$taxonomy_term);
        switch ($taxonomy_slug) {
          case 'category':
            $this->query_vars['category_name'] = $path;
            break;
          case 'post_tag':
            $this->query_vars['tag'] = $path;
            break;
          default:
            $this->query_vars['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy_slug;
            $this->query_vars['term'] = $path;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return count($taxonomy_term);
  }
}
WP_Extended::on_load();
```

Comment: Hi @Mike I am aware of the permalinks performance issue. For this particular project, the site won't exceed 20 pages, so its totally acceptable for me. And regarding your first link, it totally went way over my head. I will try reading it again. Thanks for the great answers! :)

Comment: @Ashframe - Try the code in your test site and see how it enables categories in the root. That might inform your understanding?  As for the performance issue, I usually answer as much for future readers who may not know about something as I do for the OP *(you in this case.)*

Comment: @Ashframe - I added code for you to try.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I'm attempting to use this code for the same use-case. I'm not quite getting it.. How can this be used to strip out the post type slug from the permalink?

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove the slug so that the URL structure would look like:

> http://domain.com/post-slug/

in your register_post_type set

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => false, 'with_front' => false)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Didn't work for me, does it work for you? I mean have you tested it, that it works?

Comment: Yes it works if your permalink structure is/%postname%/

Comment: Sorry didn't work for me in a fresh 3.1 install

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work.

Comment: @Bainternet do you have any ideas on this now at WP 4.3+ ?

Comment: WP 5+ too many redirects

Answer (score 0):

Although it hasn't been updated for 2 years, the below plugin worked for me:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/

FYI I'm running WP `3.9.1` with WP Types `1.5.7`