# Custom Post Type Categories URL not displaying posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I'm not as good as many wordpress developers here and I hope someone can help me, I've created a Custom post types for hotel destinations with categories for country and city. When I go to mysite.com/destinations the posts show normally. But when I try to go to a category URL (say, new york for example) by going to mysite.com/destinations/new-york I "get no posts where found".

On functions.php The only thing I have regarding the custom post types is that I only call the custom post types php page

```
require_once('hotels-manager.php');
```

On hotels-manager.php where I actually create the custom post type I have:

```
<?php 
if(!function_exists('hotel_manager_register')){
function hotel_manager_register()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Hotels Manager' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Hotel' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Hotel' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Hotel' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Hotel' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Hotel' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Hotel' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Hotel Found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Hotel Found In Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __( 'Hotels Manager' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'destinations', 'with_front' => false),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields')
    );

    register_post_type( 'destinations', $args);
}
}
add_action('init', 'hotel_manager_register');
 // hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_destinations_taxonomies', 0 );



// create two taxonomies, genres and writers for the post type "book"
if(!function_exists('create_destinations_taxonomies'))
{
    function create_destinations_taxonomies() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Hotel Regions'),
            'singular_name' => __('Region'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Regions'),
            'all_items' => __('All Regions'),
            'parent_item' => __('Parent'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent:'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Region'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Region'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Region'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Region'),
            'menu_name' => __('Regions'),
        );
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'destinations','with_front' => false ),
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'destinations', array( 'destinations', 'public' => true, ), $args ); 
    }
}

?>
```

And finally index.php simply calls:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <section class="stage">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>              
             <?php the_content('Read More...'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p><?php _e('No posts were found. Sorry!'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </section>  
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help would be really, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the same `slug` of `destinations` for both your custom post type and for your taxonomy, unfortunately by default this doesn't behave how you'd expect due to WordPress' [rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). Which caters for the default nature of posts, archives, taxonomies, slugs and the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

If this URL structure is not important to you then you could change one of your slugs to `destinations` and the other to `destination`. Ensuring you [flush your rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after doing so

Alternatively if this URL structure is important you may find [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/323249/17295) useful

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't realized that, I really don't care about different slugs. actually it worked better because mysite.com/destinations as stated display all the destinations and mysite.com/destination/newyork works better because I'm currently looking at hotels in one particular destination. Thanks!