# Remove Parents From Permalink of Hierarchical Taxonomy

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy

I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy called "places" set up with categories like so: Services > Financial Services > Financial Advisors.

The permalink for this category listing page is currently mysite.com/places/services/financial-services/financial-advisors.

Does anyone know how I can remove the parents from my permalinks so it would simply become mysite.com/places/financial-advisors/ ?

I've searched quite a lot and cannot find an answer. There's a plugin out there called "no category parents" that achieves this for regular blog posts, but it doesn't work for custom taxonomies.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Simply set to false 'hierarchical'=>true from rewrite parameter in your register_taxonomy.
It should looks like this:

```
register_taxonomy('places', 'post', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        //here your labels
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'places', 
        'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/places/"
        'hierarchical' => false // This will avoid terms concatenation!
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin [Taxonomic SEO Permalink](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomic-seo-permalinks/).

Also check this stackexchange question. [Remove taxonomy slug from a custom hierarchical taxonomy permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-a-custom-hierarchical-taxonomy-permalink)

Hope this will solve your problem. Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried Taxonomic SEO Permalink and it doesn't seem to do what I want.  I also looked through that other question posted but I think they are talking about simply removing the CPT name from the URL?  At any rate, I tried all of the options in the thread and was unable to remove any parents from the permalink.

Comment: Well, this answer is off topic - it won't solve this problem, I guess. JWP doesn't want to remove taxonomy slug from url and I wouldn't suggest to use this plugin (it wasn't updated since 2011).