# Listing post with this way "domain.com/taxonomy/category

Tags: multi-taxonomy-query

I am triying to modify wordpress (version 3.3) for that the listing to be able to show posts from one taxomy and one category.

I have installed two plugin:

WP No Category Base WP No Taxonomy Base

These allow me to show post with this kind of url: domain[.]com/taxonomy-1 and domain[.]com/category-1

At this poing I am triying to get the results with domain[.]com/taxonomy-1/category-1

¿Which is the function about this?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to get into URL re-writing which is notoriously pretty complex.  However, there are several good answers on this site explaining how to do something similar. This one in particular

[Many to Many Taxonomies or rewrite rules?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/many-to-many-taxonomies-or-rewrite-rules#answer-61964)

I also followed the tutorial [Advanced Taxonomy Queries with Pretty Urls](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/)... which is very similar in scope.

Comment: Thank you, your links were very usefull. To achieve "taxonomy/category" form, is necessary to store a rule for each combination. At this point, i have choiced to have a base for each concept. Solution in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'location/(.+)/category/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?location=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved changing base name of category and taxonomy (not removing)

In functions.php (or in plugin if you want).

You must put this code to rewrite this url www.example.org/en/[mylocation]/de/[mycategory]

```
  add_action('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules'); 
  add_filter('category_rewrite_rules' , 'add_rules' ) ;  

  function flush_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

  }

  function add_rules($rules) 
  {
    /**
     * Loop em.
     * -------------------------------------------- */    

    $feed_rule  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]';
    $paged_rule = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]';
    $base_rule  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]';

    $rules['en/([^/]+)/de/([^/]+)/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = $feed_rule;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/de/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']                  = $paged_rule;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/de/([^/]+)/?$']                                    = $base_rule;

    $feed_rule2  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
    $paged_rule2 = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
    $base_rule2  = 'index.php?location=$matches[1]';

    $rules['en/([^/]+)/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = $feed_rule2;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']                  = $paged_rule2;
    $rules['en/([^/]+)/?$']                                  = $base_rule2;


    return $rules;

  }
```

Comment: Glad you have this sorted.  One item of note, you should not flush the re-write rules on the init hook.  This means the rules will be flushed and re-written every time your site loads.  This is very inefficient.  The rules can be flushed simply by re-saving your permalinks.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, so, please, ¿what is the action to save permalinks?

Comment: In the admin, go to Options->Permalinks and then save changes.