# Custom post types and custom variables -- add_rewrite_tag() question

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm stuck on this, and have no idea what I'm doing. I have a custom post type called areas, that is hierarchical. We want to pass a variable into the page, and have it be pretty. Currently, it is:

```
http://www.example.com/area/alabama/birmingham/?action=places
```

We'd like it to be:

```
http://www.example.com/area/alabama/birmingham/places/
```

I've been mucking around with `add_rewrite_tag()` now for several hours, and just can't get this to work.

```
function create_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // Define custom rewrite tokens
    $rewrite_tag = '%places%';

    // Add the rewrite tokens
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( $rewrite_tag, 'area/(.+?)/places/', 'action=places' );

    // Define the custom permalink structure
    $rewrite_keywords_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . "area/%pagename%/$rewrite_tag/";

    // Generate the rewrite rules
    $new_rule = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_keywords_structure );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rule + $wp_rewrite->rules;

    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
} 

function add_custom_page_variables( $public_query_vars ) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'action';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'create_custom_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_page_variables');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function add_places_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%action%','([^&]+)');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_places_rewrite_tags' );
```

First add the rewrite tag action (action=xxxx)

```
function add_places_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^area/([^/]*)/places/?','index.php?post_type=area&name=$matches[1]&action=places','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^area/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/places/?','index.php?post_type=area&name=$matches[2]&action=places','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_places_rewrite_rules' );
```

Then add a custom rewrite rule. (post_type=area may be different if you made a custom slug for the posttype, use the posttype name).

Remember to flush your rewrite rules to make this work (go to your permalink settings).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another question very similar to yours with a working answer... See if it helps.

[Custom page with variables in url. Nice url with add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/custom-page-with-variables-in-url-nice-url-with-add-rewrite-rule)

Comment: Nope, that's not any real help. Possibly because I don't understand the regex they are doing.