# Using wp_redirect and .htaccess to re-route searches (and pass along the remaining GET vars)

Tags: functions, search, htaccess, wp-redirect, home-url

I'm trying to use `wp_redirect()` to redirect searches to a format that I have established in `.htaccess`.  Unfortunately, I'm running into some problems doing this.

I need to redirect search to a series of folders, and then append the remaining parameters to then end of the URL, the end result would look like this:

```
http://www.xxxxxxx.com/search/Used/MT/Billings/?s=BMW&z=59105&r=150&m=150000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&submit=Refine
```

I've written this function so far:

```
function redirect_search() {
    $var_status = var_status();
    $var_ci = var_ci();
    $var_st = var_st();
    if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
        wp_redirect(home_url("/search/".$var_status.'/'.$var_ci.'/'.$var_st));
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_search' );
```

This function results in the url looking like this: `http://www.xxxxxxx.com/search/New/Billings/MT`

I've added the parameters into it, and the function looks like this:

```
function redirect_search() {
    $var_status = var_status();
    $var_ci = var_ci();
    $var_st = var_st();
    $zip = var_z();
    $radius = var_r();
    if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
        wp_redirect(home_url("/search/".$var_status.'/'.$var_ci.'/'.$var_st.'/?s='.get_search_query().'&z='.$zip.'&r='.$radius.'etc... etc...'));
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_search' );
```

Unfortunately, this approach seems to cancel out the folders that were created, and the resulting url looks like this:

```
http://www.xxxxxxx.com/search/?s=BMW&z=59101
```

Any ideas on how to get both the folders and the parameters in there?  Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you move your appended path out of the the `home_url()` call?  For example, `wp_redirect( home_url() . '/search/' . $var_status . '/' . $var_ci . '/' . $var_st . '/?s=' . get_search_query() . '&z=' . $zip . '&etc...' );`

Comment: Nope, just tried it and it still jumps to http://www.xxxxxxx.com/search/?s=BMW

Comment: I've also tried including the folders in the home_url() and leaving the parameters outside of it, and that's giving me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***haha*** That one is actually pretty funny. You literally did shoot yourself in the foot.

Have a look at the source-code  [link-template.php line 1922](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.5/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1922) says:

```
if ( ! empty( $path ) && is_string( $path ) && strpos( $path, '..' ) === false )
```

The last condition `strpos( $path, '..' )` is actually matched by the `.'etc... etc...'` in your example. The `$path` param in `home_url()` is checked for containing any `..` to prevent directory traversal attacks. The `$path` param is only added to the url if it's not containing any `'..'`. Just remove this and you'll be one step further.

The next step is that any url containing `/search/anything-else` is treated as a search-results page in wordpress. The default pattern is `search/(.+)/?$` You can see this through installing the [Rewrite analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin and just filter for the string `search/anything-else`.

So you will need to make sure that the url `/search/Used/MT/Billings/` is actually triggering your search logic here instead of the wordpress search. Otherwise your search url in the form of `/search/test/test/test4/?s=asdasd&z=test&r=test` would actually create a redirect loop, cause you use the permalink version `/search/term` together with the `$_GET` param version `?s=term`.

This is not really a part of your question but just that you consider: Even if the redirect is working correctly in the first part, wordpress might decide to reformat the URL at the pageload following the redirect, cause it doesn't recognize your search url structure, that is why you will need to make sure that your logic is executed on all that urls before wordpress does so.

For example you could add an own rewrite rule using [add_rewrite_rule()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), or hook to the `parse_request` action (which is a good action to handle custom url params in my opinion). Of course you could also handle this external (before wordpress) through adding some custom stuff to the .htacces or even through adding a directory structure `/search/Used/MT/Billings/index.php` (that may be the easiest way, but I wouldn't recommend that cause that might get overridden by performaning a wordpress update later).

---

### Edit

According to your newest comment, I really belief you may be better of using some rewrite rules, which take effect before wordpress, instead of messing around with Wordpress core/Relevanssi. I wouldn't use it in a plugin, but it will maybe fit just right for a custom development.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/page/([1-9]) /page/$4/?status=$1&st=$2&ci=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /?status=$1&st=$2&ci=$3 [QSA]
```

That rule will internally rewrite this URL:

```
/search/Used/MT/Billings/?s=BMW&z=59105&r=150&m=150000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&submit=Refine
```

To this URL (which is in my understanding the form Relevanssi will need it):

```
?status=Used&st=MT&ci=Billings&s=BMW&z=59105&r=150&m=150000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&submit=Refine
```

*You may want to replace the `(.*)` with some more specific regular expressions, regarding the possible contents of your query vars.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, s1lv3r!  I'm sorry about the '...' in my example code; those were actually intended to indicate that I had several more parameters that I was trying to introduce after the once that were in my example.  Thank you for clarifying for me!  I'll try out the rewrite analyzer, though it's starting to feel like I'm trying to get a square peg into a round hole with this project.  Regards!

Comment: What I should have asked in the first place: Are you planning on expanding the wordpress search, replacing it or do you need both the native wp search and your custom search? If you want both, `/search` in your permalink may give you a hard time.

[Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71305/when-should-add-rewrite-tag-be-used) is a great post to start with custom permalinks.

Comment: Thanks for the link; very informative.  We're actually using the Relevanssi search plugin with custom filters to filter out searches appropriately; we're passing the necessary information for the search query through URL parameters.  From a technical perspective, this method is working great for us; unfortunately the URLs become huge, and aren't pretty at all.  As a result, we're trying to create a prettier URL structure that the Wordpress search can redirect too.  I'm unsure if this is the most efficient way of doing it, but until the URL issue, it's been working just fine.

Comment: @DEUTSCHWULF I updated my answer regarding the new information.

Comment: That redirect works great!  The problem now is that when you actually submit a search it doesn't conform to that redirect; instead it just uses Wordpress's standard /?s=&status=&st= format.  It also seems to be messing up pagination.

Comment: The redirect was only intended to solve the second step (passing the vars of the new URL format back to Relevanssi). To change the original URL you'll still need the code from your fist post. Regarding the pagination. What's exactly the problem with it? Do you have a demo site you can show?

Comment: Here's the site that we're currently working on; http://www.agentauto.com/?s=Subaru&z=59101&ci=Billings&st=MT&r=83&m=75000&pmin=1000&pmax=37000&status=Used&submit=Refine .  The problem with pagination was that after using the redirect I'd get a 404 on all pages after the first page.  Here's the URL for the redirected page: http://www.agentauto.com/search/Used/Montana/Billings/?s=Subaru&z=59101&r=83&m=75000&pmin=1000&pmax=37000&submit=Refine  Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: hmmmmm.... I see. Hard to debug without having the actual environment, but you may have a try on the updated rule from my answer.

Comment: That permalink redirect worked perfectly!  I think I've got it working now the best it's going to get.  Thanks for your help, s1lv3r; much appreciated!