# Making extra parameters optional

Tags: rewrite-rules, regex, parameter

I've setup a very specific function and it works well but I'd like to make the parameters optional but I can't get a handle on the regex bit:

```
add_rewrite_rule('whats-on/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=71&event_year=$matches[1]&event_month=$matches[2]&event_day=$matches[3]','top');
```

`/whats-on/2012/01/25` I'll show all events on this date.

`/whats-on/2012/01` goes to 404 but I'd like the parameter to be optional so I can show all January dates and the same for `/whats-on/2012` all dates in year 2012

Any help will gratefully received - thanks

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

1. Your rule isn't particularly specific. For numeric matches you should be specific about it and specify a) digits and b) how many digits. Year would be `([0-9]{4})`, month/day would be `([0-9]{1,2})`.
2. You can't do it with one rule. Add three separate rules instead.

   ```
   add_rewrite_rule( 'whats-on/([0-9]{4})/?$', 'index.php?page_id=71&event_year=$matches[1]','top');
   add_rewrite_rule( 'whats-on/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$', 'index.php?page_id=71&event_year=$matches[1]&event_month=$matches[2]','top');
   add_rewrite_rule( 'whats-on/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$', 'index.php?page_id=71&event_year=$matches[1]&event_month=$matches[2]&event_day=$matches[3]','top');
   ```

Comment: Just a note: You need to add the most specific rule first, and the most general rule last; thus the other way around as per the answer above.

Comment: @Werner No, each rule there is being add to the "top" of the list. See the final parameter. Therefore the order is correct as given.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be the correct regex:

```
add_rewrite_rule('whats-on/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=71&event_year=$matches[1]&event_month=$matches[2]&event_day=$matches[3]','top');
```

Notice the `*`s instead of `+`s.
I figure in your url at least the `year` parameter must be supplied so I left the `+` unchanged there.
**Update:** I checked it again and I found that there is a `?` missing. here is correct pattern:

```
(^whats-on/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it still goes to a 404 if I try the two examples in my original post. I was looking at this question to compare to see if I can get it optional http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/custom-page-with-variables-in-url-nice-url-with-add-rewrite-rule

Comment: I've had a chance to look at its again and with this 'whats-on/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' I get a 404 with this url /whats-on/2012/01 but not /whats-on/2012. Of course this /whats-on/2012/01/25 remains fine. Don't know what it is but I can't get my head round these patterns at all.

Comment: If you could include your function here, that would help me help you better. I check the pattern above `preg_match` and it works fine.

Comment: `code`function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'event_year';
 $public_query_vars[] = 'event_month';
 $public_query_vars[] = 'event_day';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');

function do_rewrite() {
 add_rewrite_rule('whats-on/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=71&event_year=$matches[1]&event_month=$matches[2]&event_day=$matches[3]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');`code`

Comment: Added an update.

Comment: I tried it on a fresh install of WordPress and I get the same issue /whats-on/2012 is fine, whats-on/2012/01 goes to 404 and whats-on/2012/01/28 is fine. I looked at that permalink analyzer  plugin and it appears it thinks the second value is a page number when the URL is going to the 404 for this whats-on/2012/01. Is there any way to sort this? Again any help would be fantastic

Comment: I don;t think this answer is great, firstly it's way too loose, also the way the "optional" sections are done is not rebust, that rule would match /whats-on/2012/01ad25, better to encapsulate it including the / like this:
  
    /whats-on/([\d]+)(/([\d]+))?(/([\d]+))?/?

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with

```
add_rewrite_rule('foo/bar/?([^/]+)?/?$','index.php?pagename=whatever','top');
```

matching `foo/bar`, `foo/bar/` but also `foo/bar/optionalParam`

So called non-matching brackets `(?:(/.*))` btw. do not work.
I do not even end up correctly in the rewrite array. To check such things:

I strongly recommend you get the (free) [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to see your rules in effect, and equally important, see how they compare with the regular wordpess rules as role models. Better to stick with their conventions.