# Change Query String to pretty permalink

Tags: url-rewriting, query, rewrite-rules

I have a link 
http://www.example.com/my-account/view-pet/?pet-page=2

I want to change it to either

- http://www.example.com/my-account/view-pet/pet-page/2
  or
- http://www.example.com/my-account/view-pet/2

Here's what I have tried to so far

```
function wpse12065_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule('view-pet(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=my-account/view-pet&pet-page=$matches[2]',
        'top');
}
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'wpse12065_init' ) );
```

I am able to get the `?pet-page=2` using `get_query_var( 'pet-page' )`

I have also had a look through the [THIS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/custom-page-with-variables-in-url-nice-url-with-add-rewrite-rule?rq=1) and its still not working

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Try this rewrite rule in your `functions.php`

```
function string_url_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%pet-page%', '([^&]+)');
    //In the rewrite rule you need to enter page slug and page id
    add_rewrite_rule('^Enter_Page_slug/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=Enter_Page_ID&pet-page=$matches[1]', 'top');

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
add_action('init', 'string_url_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

Now you also need to change the format of URL in `anchor tag`. For example, your previous URL

```
http://www.example.com/my-account/view-pet/?pet-page=2
```

Change this URL into this

```
http://www.example.com/my-account/view-pet/2
```

To fetch value of `pet-page` use following method

```
//Storing the value of 'pet-page' in variable
$value = get_query_var( 'pet-page' );
if($value){  //checking if variable has any value or not
    echo 'This is the value '.$value;
} else {
    echo 'No Values';
}
```

**Note:** If this don't work then flush your permalinks. For that, go to `setting -> permalink` and save changes.

Comment: No changes. I tired but but`get_query_var( 'pet-page' );` is not retruning

Comment: @bagpipper Have you enter `page_slug` and `page_ID` in code that I gave for your `functions.php`? If yes then show exact code that you enter in your functions.php from my answer so that I can find out any mistake/error.

Comment: @bagpipper And also, while fetching data with `get_query_var( 'pet-page' );` is it showing `else` statement message (No Values) or its showing `error 404` (page not found). I am assuming you are using url like this `http://www.example.com/my-account/view-pet/2` in anchor tag. And also don't forget to flush permalink as I shown in Note in my answer.

Comment: I actually need this in a plugin rather than the themes functions.php