# Search page for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, templates, search

I am new to wordpress and a beginner coder, and i was searching around the net, found solutions but still does not work.

I have custom post type named `dlm_download`, and my custom search template not working

I added the following to my `functions.php` file - the code is [from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89945/385) by @Ronald.

```
function template_chooser($template)
{
  global $wp_query;
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
  if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'dlm_download' )
  {
    return locate_template('archive-download.php');
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

Created the `archive-download.php`

and when i preform my custom search, i get the url like this `mysite.com/?dlm_download=699` nothing happens i just get redirected to my home page.

Could please someone tell what i am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom search for custom post type?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type)

Comment: First, keep in mind that _any content_ on this site is CC-BY-SA 3.0 licensed. This means that you can't randomly copy/paste code around without stating the source and the copyright owner/creator of that code. I [edit]ed your question to clearly state that (thanks @PieterGoosen for the link). Second, please clarify what you expected, where the `archive-download.php` file is located, etc. All in an [edit].

Comment: @kaiser sorry and thank you. ( Pieter Goosen) Not a possible duplicate, i already told i was searching a lot did not work including that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply include a custom search function into your search by using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

You can do something like this

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'your-custom-post-type' );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```