# Need help setting up a search form for wordpress

Tags: wp-query, query, search, genesis-theme-framework

I want to set up a search function as a widget in wordpress. This is the situation that I have.

1- I have 3 custom post types
1.a: Each post type has custom fields and taxonomies.

1. I have regular wordpress section with categories and tags.

So this is what I want the search to do:

There will be a selection option in the search form, and when the user is going to search they will select from the following:

a. entire site
b. post type a
c. post type B
d. Post type D

Thank you for your help. Please avoid suggesting a plugin. I am looking for custom functions that will search custom fields, custom taxonomies, and the post types.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You can achieve what you're searching with this already answered question.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type

Comment: I will give this a shot and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for no plugin suggestion but I thought I'd share the solution I commonly use for creating advanced search forms in WordPress.

http://wpadvancedsearch.com/

This is not a plugin but a PHP framework for building advanced search forms in WordPress. It has served me especially well with custom post types and creating search forms that filter results using custom meta values, taxonomies and more.

The framework enables you to set up a customized search form that displays result using variables passed from your search form to WP_Query.

You could use this framework either in your theme or in a plugin. Their documentation is also very good.

Hope this helps!

Herman

Comment: I am actually familiar with this framework. However, I am looking to add somehing hat is as simple as possible.