# Searching post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, theme-development, search, location-search

Is it possible to take a user input from a search form, use that to search a custom post type via the `WP_Query` class and then redirect the user to a page template to display the results?

For example,

Assume you have a search input that takes `city`, `state` or `zip` You then enter in California, next that input is then captured and the WP_Query is used to then search custom post type "Locations". It finds 4 locations matching, you are then redirected to page "Locations" which then displayed all 4 locations.

How would you do this?

**Note**: This is not a home work assignment, this a client feature. Yes there are plugins but due to how this is customized and how they want it laid out, it has to be built from the ground up.

Comment: The answer is (almost universally) — yes, it is possible. Now what had you tried? Are you building this as part of "normal" search, or completely separate from it? What "page Locations" is precisely and technically?

Comment: I thnk you want this?
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type

Comment: @Rarst This is completely separate from regular search. I haven't tried anything because I didn't know if this was possible. Page locations is really just a page template that would render either all locations from  post type or the ones that match. Essentially just a loop for this custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and simple method might be to create a custom page template and have the search form send the user to the page that you create with it.

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: Location Results
*/
if ( isset($_REQUEST['search_field_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['search_field_name']) ) {
    # Read and escape the input data
    # Do your query, grab your results
    # Display your results to the user
} else {
    # No results found. Display search form again with note to enter something.
}
```

You could then create a new page, selecting this page template and edit your form to send the results to it.

There are other ways to do this, but this is a fairly quick and easy method that I use now and again.