# query_vars overriding WP_Query args

Tags: wp-query, search

Looking for some fresh eyes on this,

I have a custom archive for my CPT and it's Taxonomies.

The page has a input search form to filter posts of the CPT as well as drop downs to filter by terms.

The issue is that on page load, when the loop instantiates WP_Query args are overridden by `get_query_vars`.

For example, the `posts_per_page` is set to 2. 
However, `query_vars` hijacks the args and changes it to 12 (for some reason, not declared anywhere else on the site)

Logic below.

```
$q = get_query_var( 'q' ); 


$args = array(
    'post_type'      => $post_type, 
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, // tried 2
    'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
    's'              => $q
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Form - see `q` as value

```
 <form id="filter-form" role="search" method="get" class="" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
 <!-- Query -->
<label>
<span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Enter Keyword', 'label' )?></span>
<input type="search" class="search-field"
       placeholder="Keywords"
       value="<?= $q ?>"
       name="q"
       title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Enter Keyword', 'label' ) ?>"/>
</label>
etc
```

The filter is registered and hooked in functions.php as per codex

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "q";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a simple conditional prior to setting up the query

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = get_query_var( 'q' );
} else{
    // otherwise null, nothing to see here
    $q = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing, but there's a trivial solution

### Use The `s` parameter with a `pre_get_posts` filter

Using `s` as the name of your input will allow you to do a direct search via the main query, speeding up the page load.

Additionally, you can then modify the search using the `pre_get_posts` filter to add the other parameters you want, e.g.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q ) {
    if ( !$q->is_main_query() || !$q->is_search() ) {
        return;
    }
    $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    // etc...
} );
```

#### But I Don't Want To Use `search.php`, I A Different Template For This Particular Thing

That would be another question you should ask separately, but luckily, somebody beat you to it:

[How to create a custom search for custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I solved my own issue with a simple check.

`$q` should not have been assigned to `get_query_var()` on page load.

I've added a simple conditional to check if we a keyword has been entered.

`
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
 $q = get_query_var( 'q' );
} else{
    $q = null;
}
`

Comment: You should post that as an answer

Comment: Sure, I'll post it now. Not sure if it's the best convention but it solved our issue here. This logic will be used for multiple archives like this so we shall see how it fairs

Thanks Tom!