# Creating a search results page from a custom post type in a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I have a forum system where I created a custom post type, and I would like to have a search system for the topics, but I do not know what the structure would be, for example, how the file will be and the search form action.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here, but it is treated as if I wanted a custom post type of a theme, in my case I created it as a Plugin, someone would have a light there of how I can create a search within a custom post type but that is Inside a plugin?

[How to create a custom search for custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in your search

```
global $query_string;

wp_parse_str($query_string, $search_query);
//add post type.
$post_type = array('post_type'=>'your-custom-post-type');
$combine_search = array_merge($search_query,$post_type);

$search = new WP_Query($combine_search);
```