# How to add Search URL parameters to a Page Template Page for Custom Post Type

Tags: url-rewriting, search

**Scenario:**
 I have a custom post type **"book"** which the archives are displayed in a page  **"book-list"** using custom page template. 
Currently, 
`index.php?post_type=book gets redirected to this /book-list/` page 
`index.php?post_type=book&s=scifi gets redirected to /book-list/` without search result

`/book-list/?s=scifi` leads to a 404

**What I want:**
 to add search functionality and result pages with pagination to search custom post type book by using `/book-list/?s=scifi&paged=2` or preferably `/book-list/search/scifi/page/2/`

How do I approach this?

Comment: Can you please share with me a code you have used for that so I can help you.

Comment: I dont really have a code right now, i have tried using the below, which still leads to a 404. 

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
 add_rewrite_rule('^book-list/?s=([^/]*)', 'index.php?post_type=book&s=$matches[1]', 'top');
 }
 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic', 10, 0);

Comment: you should have to try like this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89945/62026

Comment: Thanks for giving me the direction. Let me try this out.

Comment: Okay try it and let me know either it's working or not as you requested.