Multiple search forms and respective results page templates?
I have a Woocommerce site and I would like to set up two different search forms, one for products and one for everything else (pages, posts, and a couple CPTs) that would render on it's own respective search results template. Is this possible?

I believe the solution of the same already discussed here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type

This question is similar to: How to create a custom search for custom post type?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
