# Hijacking the URL for filtering

Tags: url-rewriting, filters, urls, htaccess

Right, here's the deal. I've got a loop of which displays news posts, these posts can belong to special categories (not normal categories) and I want to be able to filter by them.

If I wasn't too interested in aesthetics I'd use a link like this:

```
domain.com/news?filter=cat1
```

But instead what I want to do is this (» rewritten):

```
domain.com/news/cat1 » domain.com/news/?filter=cat1
```

I've modified the `.htaccess` to pass the `cat1` value as a GET variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/$ /news/?filter=$1 [L,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem is even though this is now successfully passing the `filter` variable in, WordPress treats the `/cat1/` as a page, it obviously cannot find it and thus throws a 404.

Is there a way to allow this particular URL rewriting without WordPress firing a 404? It appears it's taking the URL in the address bar and parsing that, what I really want is for it to parse the rewritten URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress also has a rewriting mechanism, it's better to use that instead of doing it in the `.htaccess` file.

You can add your own rewrite rules to it. In your case we want to store the `cat1` part in a separate query variable, so we also need to tell WordPress to allow this query variable (it uses a whitelist for safety).

The precise form of the rewrite rule depends on what `http://domain.com/news/` is: is it a Page with a custom template, or something else? You should find this out (using my [Rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) for example), and add this to the rewrite rule.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse16819_init' );
function wpse16819_init()
{
    // Base form, will probably not work because it does nothing with the `news` part
    add_rewrite_rule( 'news/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?wpse16819_filter=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    // Use this instead if `news` is a page
    add_rewrite_rule( 'news/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?wpse16819_filter=$matches[1]&pagename=news', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse16819_query_vars' );
function wpse16819_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse16819_filter';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Remember to *flush* the rewrite rules (save them to the database) after you add this code. You can do this by visting the *Permalinks* page in the admin area.

You can now access the `wpse16819_filter` variable with `get_query_var( 'wpse16819_filter' );`.

Comment: That's looking more promising, I'll have a good look at that tonight and report back, cheers Jan! :-)