# Change author base slug for different roles

Tags: url-rewriting, slug, user-roles

Is it possible to change the author base slug according to his role? For example, authors get example.com/ninja/%username% and subscribers get example.com/trainee/%username%?

I am thinking of something like:

```php
add_action('init', 'set_new_author_base');
function set_new_author_base() {
  global $wp_rewrite;

  if($user->role == 'subscriber')
    $author_slug = 'trainee';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
  } elseif($user->role == 'author') {
    $author_slug = 'ninja';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
  }
}
```

It should work for unregistered visitors if they browse the site and it should work for the logged in authors and subscribers themselves.

Comment: [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-author-slug/) does what you're after. If you don't want to use a plugin you might be able to find the answer to your question in the source code.

Comment: I think it is not possible by touching the author base. You’ll have to set up a separate rewrite rule and filter the author permalink.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example, the author rewrite pattern changes from `/author/[authorname]/` to `/[author_level]/[author_name]/`. If we allow `[author_level]` to be anything, we will get into conflict with the rules for pages, because `/[anything]/[anything]/` can be either an author archive or a regular subpage.

For this reason, my solution assumes you have a limited number of author levels, so we can explicitly put them in the rewrite rules. So `/ninja/[anything]/` will be an author archive, but `/not-ninja/[anything]/` will be a regular page.

Changing the URL structure always consists of two parts: changing the URLs that WordPress will accept and changing the URLs that WordPress will generate. First we will change the URLs that WordPress will accept by introducing a new *rewrite tag* and setting our author base to that tag.

```
// I assume you define these somewhere, this is just to make the example work
$wpse17106_author_levels = array( 'trainee', 'ninja' );

add_action( 'init', 'wpse17106_init' );
function wpse17106_init()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_levels = $GLOBALS['wpse17106_author_levels'];

    // Define the tag and use it in the rewrite rule
    add_rewrite_tag( '%author_level%', '(' . implode( '|', $author_levels ) . ')' );
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = '%author_level%';
}
```

If you check the resulting rewrite rules with [my Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) you will notice that it contains extra rules for the plain `/[author-level]/` pages. This happens because WordPress generates rules for each directory part that contains a rewrite tag, like `%author_level%`. We don't need these, so filter out all author rewrite rules that don't contain an `author_name`:

```
add_filter( 'author_rewrite_rules', 'wpse17106_author_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse17106_author_rewrite_rules( $author_rewrite_rules )
{
    foreach ( $author_rewrite_rules as $pattern => $substitution ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $substitution, 'author_name' ) ) {
            unset( $author_rewrite_rules[$pattern] );
        }
    }
    return $author_rewrite_rules;
}
```

Now WordPress should accept URLs using this new pattern. The only thing left to do is change the URLs it generates when it creates a link to an author archive. For that you can hook into the `author_link` filter, like this very basic example:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpse17106_author_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse17106_author_link( $link, $author_id )
{
    if ( 1 == $author_id ) {
        $author_level = 'ninja';
    } else {
        $author_level = 'trainee';
    }
    $link = str_replace( '%author_level%', $author_levels, $link );
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: But aren’t `trainee/john/` and `ninja/john/` now both valid URIs for the same author? There is no way to create a canonical permalink for one author just by changing the rewrite rules, right? A `user_meta` could help …

Comment: Yes, they are both valid, but if you use the standard functions only one of them will be linked to, via the `author_link` filter. You can also add an extra "canonical check" just like the core `redirect_canonical()` does, if you really care about this. I don't know how `user_meta` will help here? My `author_link` example is too simple, it needs site-specific logic to separate the ninjas from the trainees.

Comment: This is still a really nice solution, thank you so much! what to you mean with site-specific logic?

Comment: @dotwired: Well, because I don't know how your site defines which users are ninjas and which are trainees, you will have to complete that `author_link` filter yourself. (Actually you did tell it - Authors are ninjas and Subscribers are trainees - but my code should be enough to complete that part and be generic enough so others can learn from it too.)

Comment: Does `author_rewrite_rules` run on every page load?

Comment: @henrywright: No, the rewrite rules filters are only triggered when you flush the rewrite rules.