# How do I create a dynamic page?

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to create something similar to what buddypress does with member pages. For eg;
http://www.example.com/members/foo

http://www.example.com/members/bar

etc.

I tried looking up the buddypress code and I see that they don't use custom post type or a custom taxonomy. It also doesn't look like they are using add_rewrite_rule() too.

I would like to have something similar, where my plugin will take 'foo' from the URL and generate content on basis of that. What's the best way to do it?

**UPDATE:**

I followed instructions on this thread, which is exactly what I wanted: [How to create a front end user profile with a friendly permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink)

Here's the code:

```
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'analytics_rewrite_add_var' );
function analytics_rewrite_add_var( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'analytic';
    return $vars;
}
function add_analytic_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%analytic%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^analytics/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?analytic=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_analytic_rewrite_rule');
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'analytics_rewrite_catch' );
function analytics_rewrite_catch()
{
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'analytic', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        include ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/html/analytics.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

However, /analytics/foo/ still gives me a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you clarify ... what is the content on the page you want? if you want a page for each Author (like members in BuddyPress) then this is possible

Comment: The content can be anything. For the sake of discussion let say, I just want to echo the last part of the URL, i.e. "foo" or "bar".

Comment: could it be a get variable rewriten? like `?members=foo` to `members/foo` ? So we can have one page that changes according to the get variable.

Comment: @DeepakMittal please clarify the *taxonomy* you want example  /category/foo   or /tag/foo  WordPress has to know what foo is. If foo is the TITLE of  a post then /foo is just a post or page title

Comment: @Damien Its just a random string. It can be anything. And there's no taxonomy.

Comment: Note that you have to re-save permalinks whenever you make a change like this. Visit the Settings->Permalinks page and save. This saves the new rule in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer. And for future references, Deepak, you need to actually post the solution as an answer. Instead, you posted your answer within your own question and then made a comment about it. Please don't do that.

```
function analytics_rewrite_add_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'analytic';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'analytics_rewrite_add_var' );

function add_analytic_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%analytic%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^analytics/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?analytic=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_analytic_rewrite_rule');

function analytics_rewrite_catch() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'analytic', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        include ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/html/analytics.php');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'analytics_rewrite_catch' );
```

Comment: @Deepak - What you're supposed to do, if you find the solution to your own question, is simply leave the question as the question and post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks guy. I may have not been clear with my question. I was having this exact same problem:
[How to create a front end user profile with a friendly permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink)

I fixed it with the code I've pasted in my question above. I had forgotten to flush the rules, which MadLem on IRC asked me to do and it's working now.

Sorry for not being clear, and thanks for taking time to answer :)

Comment: Deepak, I think the code you posted in the update should be inside this Answer instead...

Comment: Thought copy-pasting same code wouldn't be a good idea.