# How to filter posts by format and category via url?

Tags: categories, permalinks, post-formats

I figured out I can filter posts by format just by doing /type/{format} e.g. /type/gallery/ in the url.

Looking for a way to filter by categories on top of this, something like /type/gallery/category/installation or /type/gallery/art.

I've figured out the query, but I don't know how to handle the url bit:

```
$galleryquery = wp_parse_args($query_string);
$galleryquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'terms' => array('post-format-gallery'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array('installation'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
);
query_posts($galleryquery);
```

Ideas? I'm guessing I have to intercept the permalink and somehow pass it to my query...

Site is reachable [here](http://dev.thegarage-cville.com/type/gallery/)

Comment: Ok, filtering out post formats _did_ work out for you like this: `/type/{post_format}`. Now let's try to do this: `/type/{post_format}/?category=installation`. Does it work?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ehm... did you uncomment/remove your code before you tried that? Have you deactivated all plugin? Switched back to Twenty Ten?

Comment: Yes, see http://dev.thegarage-cville.com/type/gallery/?category=installation

Comment: No, you haven't. There's a permanent redirect to `wp-login.php`...

Comment: Herp derp, guess it would be nice if others could see my site! Removed redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
function when_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $newrules = array();
  $new_rules['type/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]';
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules','when_rewrite_rules');
```

There is no need to add new query vars. You can get both taxonomies out of the box: categories are query-able with "?category_name=x" and post formats with "?post_format=x".

Confusingly, post formats are a taxonomy, and **not** a custom post type, yet have the taxonomy of "type". E.g. you filter them like so:

> mysite.com/type/gallery

Seems like "/format/" would be a better taxonomy to avoid confusion with Custom Post Type.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar, but for member pages. I was able to use the code in my answer linked here which parses the information in the URL which can be manipulated within WordPress.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91399/12920

Here's a snippet of the URL handling portion which perhaps will get you started? Granted you're doing something different than me, but the underlying function should be very similar.

```
// Catch the URL and redirect it to a template file
function userpage_rewrite_catch() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'member', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        // Do something if member is in the URL
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/user-profile.php');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'userpage_rewrite_catch' );
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to create a new rewrite rule to handle the custom url. I haven't tested the code, but it goes something like this:

```
function add_category_query_var($query_vars) {
    array_push($query_vars, 'post_type');
    array_push($query_vars, 'post_category');
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars','add_category_query_var');

/* create new rewrite rule*/
function add_category_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite_rules) {

        $new_rewrite_rule['type/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&post_category=$matches[2]';

        $wp_rewrite_rules = $new_rewrite_rule + $wp_rewrite_rules;

        return $wp_rewrite_rules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_category_rewrite_rule');
```

Then you would access the new variable like so:

```
$galleryquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'terms' => array('post-format-gallery'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array($_GET['post_category']),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
);
```

Comment: yes, I think I would want to go this route. However, when I try to enter http://dev.thegarage-cville.com/index.php?post_type=gallery&post_category=music it redirects to http://dev.thegarage-cville.com/?post_type=gallery&post_category=music and just loads the blog index. I take it I need to get the Public query vars working first. Thoughts?

Comment: Save the WordPress permalinks first to trigger the activation of the new rewrite rule. Also confirm that it's indeed picking the new variables.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, thanks, although adding the variables was unneeded for what I asked.