# Use different template than author.php for get_author_posts_url()

Tags: author-template, template-hierarchy

I have a client that wants two pages for each author profile:

First Page - has user info, bunch of social media links, etc. Using author.php for this.
Second Page - list of author posts

I've built everything, and here's my question:

**Is there a way to have get_author_posts_url() use a template other than author.php?**

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion: I think is easier to handle author profiles (pages with just author info, no posts) with some plugin for "user profiles", there are a lot, and keep using author.php for what it is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter called [`author_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/author-template.php#L235). You can use that change the URL to whatever you want.

```
add_filter(
  'author_link', 
  function ($link, $author_id, $author_nicename) {
    var_dump($link, $author_id, $author_nicename); // debug
    return $link; // return your modified URL
  },
  1,3
);
```

The question does not have enough detail to allow for more specific code.

You can use the `template_include` hook to alter the template that loads in much the same way as the above code alters URL.

```
function author_archive_wpse_112852($template) {
  if (/* not sure what your conditions are */) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/diff-author-template.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','author_archive_wpse_112852');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what I want to do. But how can I use template_include only when using the get_author_posts_url() function? That's the only condition.

Comment: Your condition doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `get_author_posts_url()` just creates an URL. When you click that URL you have a new request-- that function isn't involved. I suppose you could tack on a `GET` string-- `?my_special_author=true`. I am starting to think that you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Comment: Could be :( What I'm trying to say is that when clicking on the link created by get_author_posts_url(), WP automatically uses the author.php template to display the results. I want to use a different template when that link is clicked on.

Comment: Anyway, I've accepted and upvoted your answer, since it was very helpful. At least we've moved the ball forward.

Comment: The code above should let you 1) alter the URL created by `get_author_posts_url` and 2) change the template that loads. I don't understand why you want to do that or what your precise conditions are. If I did understand those issues I suspect there is another solution but until there is a better explanation....

Comment: The reason is because my client's site design includes a two-page author profile, and author.php is being used for page 1. And page 2 needs a listing of all posts. So I figured I could use get_author_posts_url to get to page 2, but that function uses author.php to display its results--and author.php is already being used by page 1. So I guess I need a list of all author posts that is linked to the initial author page. Ah! Now maybe X is X!

Comment: Ok... This is really incorrect: "that function uses author.php to display its results". `get_author_posts_url` doesn't use anything to display results-- nada. The WordPress Core determines which page is being requested and loads the appropriate template. _Where_ the URL comes from is irrelevant. You are probably going to need to get into URL rewriting. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs to solve this kind of issue, I found [another question on here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink) that contains all of the necessary steps, including those found in the accepted answer on this page.