# How to create a front end user profile with a friendly permalink and a 404 trigger

Tags: url-rewriting, users, 404-error, front-end, profiles

I've implemented the accepted answer from this question and works great:

[How to create a front end user profile with a friendly permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink/58793)

But it does not trigger a 404 if you just enter anything /user/asdasd

I'm thinking it needs to happen at some point in this section of code:

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'user', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/user-profile.php');
    exit;
}
```

So check the query_vars then maybe run that through the users database to check?

I'm not really sure how to integrate a 404 redirect if the url is not a user.

Maybe it is something that I put on user-profile.php to check if it returns anything about the user, if not, load the 404 template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution here would be as simple as you've generally described it.
Assuming conveniently that `$wp_query->query_vars['user']` contains the **username** and not its **ID**:

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'user', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    if ( username_exists( $wp_query->query_vars['user'] ) ) {
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/user-profile.php' );
    } else {
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php' );
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I added a check to see if user has a certain role before directing to the user-profile template but other than that this worked! Thanks.