# Changing author slug for a custom role without using plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks, author

I am trying to change author slug for a custom role. A role called trip_vendor is added by my plugin but I want to change the author slug only for this role. I have a function but this changes author slug for every roles so that the new url would be [example.com/operator/user](https://#).

```
add_filter( 'init', array( $this, 'wpte_vendor_profile_url' ) );        
function wpte_vendor_profile_url()
{
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $author_slug = 'operator';
        $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $author_slug . '/%author%';
}
```

I tried as suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17106/change-author-base-slug-for-different-roles) but with no help.

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add_permastruct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_permastruct/) (with `ep_mask` set to `EP_AUTHORS`) to add the proper rewrite rules, and the `author_link` filter to set the proper author URL:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_permastruct( '%author_trip_vendor%', 'operator/%author%', [
        'ep_mask' => EP_AUTHORS,
    ] );
} );

add_filter( 'author_link', function( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ){
    if ( user_can( $author_id, 'trip_vendor' ) ) {
        $link = '/operator/' . $author_nicename;
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $link ) );
    }
    return $link;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page.

### UPDATE

> non-vendors profile are loaded on URL `example.com/operator/admin` and
>   also on `example.com/author/admin`

You can fix it via one of these options:

1. Send a "404" header ("Page not found" error)

   ```
   add_action( 'parse_request', function( $wp ){
       if ( preg_match( '#^(author|operator)/([^/]+)#', $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
           $user = get_user_by( 'login', $matches[2] );
           if (
               ( 'author' === $matches[1] && $user && user_can( $user, 'trip_vendor' ) ) ||
               ( 'operator' === $matches[1] && $user && ! user_can( $user, 'trip_vendor' ) )
           ) {
               $wp->query_vars = ['error' => 404];
           }
       }
   } );
   ```
2. Redirect the user to the proper "operator" URL

   ```
   add_action( 'parse_request', function( $wp ){
       if ( preg_match( '#^(author|operator)/([^/]+)#', $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
           $user = get_user_by( 'login', $matches[2] );
           if (
               ( 'author' === $matches[1] && $user && user_can( $user, 'trip_vendor' ) ) ||
               ( 'operator' === $matches[1] && $user && ! user_can( $user, 'trip_vendor' ) )
           ) {
               $base = ( 'author' === $matches[1] ) ? 'operator' : 'author';
               wp_redirect( home_url( '/' . $base . '/' . $matches[2] ) );
               exit;
           }
       }
   } );
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Sally. I am marking it as resolved even though non-vendors profile are loaded on url example.com/operator/admin and also on example.com/author/admin. For trip_vendors, it is doing correct.

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer. It should fix the issue of having the multiple URLs.