# How do I set a custom base URL for standard posts?

Tags: permalinks

Currently, permalinks are set to /%postname%/.

I'd like to prefix "blog" before all standard posts.

I'm using several custom post types, each with their own rewrite rules in the setup.

How can I setup a custom prefix for my standard WordPress posts?

Comment: This is not that easy, I would suggest just adding a category called `blog`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you try defining your perm structure like: /blog/%postname%/

If each one of your custom post types has its own slug defined, this should work like you are asking.

Comment: It is possible that this will also add this prefix to the rewrite rules of your other custom post types. If it does, you should explicitly set the `with_front` parameter of the `rewrite` argument you use when registering the post type to `false`. Use [my Rewrite analyzer plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) to see the new structure of all your rewrite rules to prevent surprises.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Jan - Thank you for those additional details, I'll keep that in mind and take a look at the plugin accordingly - thank you!

Comment: Sweet, Jan, `with_front` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Same here! `with_front` nailed it.

Comment: note that I had to go to Settings > Permalinks and click save (without changing anything) before it took effect