# URL rewrite rules for multiple taxonomies query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create some pretty URLs for links querying multiple taxonomies. I'm using the "Taxonomy drill-down" plugin, although the main usage is now integrated @ the core it still has some helpful function for templating :)

An example URL querying multiple taxonomies ( working ) would be:
 *domain.com/?tax1=foo&tax2=bar*

My goal is to have links like - 
*domain.com/tax1/foo/tax2/bar* - translating to the above example

tax1/2 = taxonomy name

foo/bar = required term

I stumbled upon [Examples of WP Rewrites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples) but i think i suck with those patterns and something like:

```
$newrules['tax1/(.*)/tax2/(.*)/'] = 'index.php?tax1=$matches[1]&tax2=$matches[2]';
```

doesn't seem to work ( that's just a portion of the whole function based on the Wordpress example )

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(.*)` matches everything, so it will "eat up" the extra characters (it is "greedy"). If the URL is `/tax1/foo/tax2/bar/`, the first `(.*)` will be `foo/tax2/bar/`, so nothing is left for the second match.

Instead of `(.*)` you can use the "non-greedy" version `(.+?)`. This will match as much as possible, but still keep the rest in mind. You can also use the even stricter version `([^/]+)`: this will match everything up to the next `/` - but this will not work for nested categories, so `/category/fruit/banana/tag/flies/` will not split up in `fruit/banana` and `flies` like you might expect.

If you are going to play with the rewrite rules I recommend you to install my [Rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608). It allows you to see the current rewrite rules and play with URLs to see which rules will match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan, i did try tweaking it up and based on Rewrite analyzer ( awesome plugin ) it should work, but i keep getting a 404 error. It must be an issue from the drill-down plugin side.

Comment: @netfreak: `add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/tag/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]', 'top' );` works for me. The Taxonomy drill-down widget does not generate links in that format, but if I go to a URL like `/category/banana/tag/hello/` it does only display posts in the category `banana` and with tag `hello`.

Comment: You rock. i used your latest snippet and now the rewrite works, possible the "/?" at the end? ( i need to study on RegExp asap :) )

Comment: @netfreak: Er, I see I missed a final `$` too, so it might match too much. `category/(.+?)/tag/([^/]+)/?$` should be a better match - and it could be even improved to allow paging. Then it would become `add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/tag/([^/]+)(/page/(\d+))?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top' );`

Comment: @netfreak: If you figure out a nice way to make the Taxonomy drill-down plugin generate these new "pretty" URLs, please share it with us too (and with scribu, the author of the plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the revised/latest snippet again. Unfortunately, I don't actually use the widget to produce multi-taxonomy queries URLs but instead i'm taking advantage of the taxonomy.php template for single taxonomy AND multi taxonomy queries ( if/else with is_multitax() as check  ). I think though it could be done with a more loose approach on the rewrite and an additional function on QMT_URL class where URIs are constructed.

Comment: @JanFabry you can use qmt_url filter for Taxonomy drill-down URLs: https://github.com/scribu/wp-query-multiple-taxonomies/wiki/Changing-URLs