# Custom Permalinks for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have custom post types registered and they are working fine with their normal URLs. My Custom post types have 'members' as their slug. Now I am trying to have a custom permalink for my custom post types. Here is my $wp_write->add_rule

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('members/.+?/(.+)/$','index.php?post_type=pasha_members&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Below is my $wp_rewrite->rules array.

```
array(
    ['members/.+?/(.+)/$'] => 'index.php?post_type=pasha_members&name=$matches[1]'
    ['category/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] => 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]'
    ['category/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] => 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]'
   ...
);
```

And here is the url that I am trying to access, I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
http://wp.dev/members/city1-city2/best-compnay/
```

When I change Permalink settings to default in Settings->Permalink, I can access the custom post just fine using the following url.

```
http://wp.dev/?post_type=pasha_members&name=best-compnay
```

Let me know if you need more information. Any help pointers are much appreciated.

NOTE: I have put the add_rule in init instead of activate just for the testing. I also have put the flush_rewrite_rules in the init, its also temporarily until its fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that WordPress cuts off the final `/` before it starts matching the URL. So make it optional in the regex and it should work:

```
members/.+?/(.+)/?$
```

If the city and company parts will not contain slashes it could be even more clear to use `[^/]+` to match them ("everything up to a slash"). Then your regex would become:

```
members/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$
```

I created [a plugin to analyze your rewrite rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608), it is really easy to play with and debug your rules. Although you made me discover an error in it: it did not remove the final slash, so your first regex matched in my analyzer but not in the "real" WordPress. I'll update it soon!

Comment: Perfect!!! that did work. First I was using [^/]+ then I dropped it because I was not able to get it to work. Thank you.

Comment: One more question.. I want to reset the rewrite rules.. (i.e want wordpress to forget and then regenerate). so should I switch back to default in permalink settings and then back to custom. I think I messed up something now wordpress is going to home page for every url.