# Adding more pages to author pages

Tags: url-rewriting, author, slug

At the moment I have the following code for changing the author_base slug.

```
/** ADD REWRITE RULES **/
function change_author_permalinks() {
   global $wp_rewrite;

   $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'profile';
   $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

How can I add, for example, a extra "edit" page on to this, i.e., /profile/my-user-name/edit ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author rewrite rules [are filtered through `author_rewrite_rules`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L1537). You can add a rule there for the pattern `author/([^/]+)/edit/?$`, but the substitution will depend on how you want to create the `edit` page. A simple example that will set a custom query variable and load a specific template if this variable is set:

```
add_action( 'author_rewrite_rules', 'wpse18547_author_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse18547_author_rewrite_rules( $author_rules )
{
    $author_rules['author/([^/]+)/edit/?$'] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&wpse18547_author_edit=1';
    return $author_rules;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse18547_query_vars' );
function wpse18547_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse18547_author_edit';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'author_template', 'wpse18547_author_template' );
function wpse18547_author_template( $author_template )
{
    if ( get_query_var( 'wpse18547_author_edit' ) ) {
        return locate_template( array( 'edit-author.php', $author_template ) );
    }
    return $author_template;
}
```

Small tip: Don't call `flush_rules()` on every `init`, it's an expensive operation. You only need to do it when the rewrite rules change. You can manually flush the rules by just visiting the *Permalinks* settings page. And if you are going to play with the rewrite rules, I recommend you install [my Rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608).

Comment: Basically I'm going to create the page by reading the slug (that is - I'm NOT going to create a extra page and call a template file). The page itself is for subscribers to update their personal info and only they have access to it.

Comment: @EddyR: I updated my answer with some code that will load a specific template file, but you can of course do whatever you want when you detect the extra query variable.

Comment: hmmm, that seems to almost be working. I'm having a problem with get_query_var() it doesn't return anything. Do you know what would be causing that?

Comment: @EddyR: Do you have a custom query somewhere? `query_posts()`? That would override the global `$wp_query` variable, which is where `get_query_var()` looks.

Comment: Ahhh, perfect, thank you very much. I found my mistake this morning - I just forgot to change 'author/([^/]+)/edit/?$' to 'profile/([^/]+)/edit/?$'