# add_rewrite_rule and pagination issue

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination

I've got an issue, writing a correct rewrite rule.

Basically, here are the examples of the url I want :

`/myPage/mySuPage`

Then the same with pagination
`/myPage/mySuPage/page/3`

Then, the basic page, with 2 params, no pagination
`/myPage/mySuPage/param1/param2`

Then, the one with 2 parameters and the pagination
`/myPage/mySuPage/param1/param2/page/3`

More or less, i have it working with differents rules for each case, but if I put them in a row, nothing works.

Here are the rules I wrote :

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'myPage/mySuPage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=myPage/mySuPage&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]',
    'top' );

add_rewrite_rule(
    'myPage/mySuPage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]{1,})?',
    'index.php?pagename=myPage/mySuPage&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]&pageds=$matches[3]',
    'top' );


add_rewrite_rule(
    'myPage/mySuPage/(.+?)(/page/([0-9]+))?/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=myPage/mySuPage&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]',
    'top' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first two rewrite rules do not end with `$`, which indicates that the URL should stop there. So `myPage/mySuPage/param1/param2/page/3` would still be matched by the first pattern, because it can just ignored the `/page/3` part at the end. The next rewrite rules will then never be used.

With [my Rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) I was able to simplify your rewrite rules to these two: one without params and just optional paging, and one with params and optional paging. Combining these two into one did not work because the optional params woud "eat" the paging part.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'myPage/mySuPage(/page/([0-9]+)?)?/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=myPage/mySuPage&pageds=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_rule(
    'myPage/mySuPage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/page/([0-9]+)?)?/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=myPage/mySuPage&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]&pageds=$matches[4]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: Wahou, thank you very much Jan. It works perfectly now. I didn't knew about the "optional". I'm using your plugin, but i guess this was too "complex" for me.

Comment: @Ludo: Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, you can click the checkbox to [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This will also remove the question from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: is there a reason `paged` has an 's' on the end of it?

Comment: @MannyFleurmond: I think I just took the original rules from the question, and did not check the parameters. It is possible that `pageds` is a parameter that is handled by his own code.