# Rewrite rules for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

There is a nonhierarchical custom post type "news".

```
/news/
/news/page/2/
/news/post_slug/
```

Each post has custom field `"views"`. When someone opens post, field's value increased by one.

Would like to sort posts by this custom field, by its value.

```
/news/
/news/views/ = /news/?sort=views (get posts with custom field "views" and sort asc)
/news/views/page/2/ = /news/?sort=views&page=2 (similar to previous, next page)
/news/post_slug/
```

Got working `/news/?sort=views`, but this link is not human-like.

It should be transformed to `/news/views/` and be able to handle pagination.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at [`add_rewrite_tag()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) and [`add_rewrite_rule()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Also read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/add-rewrite-rule-and-pagination-issue) topics. They are very close to you issue.

After you setup rewrite rule don't forget to flush rules

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' ); // flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
    $pattern = 'news/([^/]+)?'; // the same pattern that was used in add_rewrite_rule
    if ( !isset( $rules[$pattern] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}
```

Comment: this code doesnt work

Comment: did you setup `add_rewrite_tag()` and `add_rewrite_rule()`?

Comment: I don't know how