# Redirecting when changing custom post type slugs?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, redirect

I changed the name of two of my custom post types. The original slugs for them did not properly reflect the post type. So I need to redirect requests for posts beginning with `designer_lingerie` (the old post type slug) to just `designer`. All of the posts are the same just the post type slug has changed.

I am sure I'll need to use `.htaccess` but am unsure of what to tell it to change. Basically what URL should I use to do this? The WordPress pretty URL or the default URL?

Comment: I edited the post to include your comment, you can remove the comment if you think it is unnecessary.

Comment: anytime I add an .htaccess file the Wordpress pretty URLs no longer work. I cannot find a Wordpress generated .htaccess file anywhere on my development server. Any ideas? Anyone? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a line like:

```
RewriteRule ^aboutus$ /about-us [R=301,L]
```

In to your .htaccess file. The old url should go between the ^ and $ and then new url after the slash.

Comment: how can I tell if the redirect 301 is active? That the redirect happened and not just a rewrite? Thanx

Comment: you can use a tool like Firebug to watch the Network communication when you request a URL. That rule in the .htaccess will respond with a 301 header.

Comment: cool thanx. I'll check on the redirect header in firebug

Comment: Yep, it's all good! Thanx again

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the Apache Rewrite module, but the built-in WordPress rewrite functionality. If you want to see the rules it uses, install [my Rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608). You can just duplicate the rules of your post type, with the old slug instead of the new slug. This way both URLs will link to your post content.

```
// The filter name is [post type name]_rewrite_rules, so I assume your post type name (not rewrite slug) is `designer`
add_filter( 'designer_rewrite_rules', 'wpse22625_designer_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse22625_designer_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $old_rules = array();
    foreach ( $rules as $pattern => $substitution ) {
        $old_pattern = str_replace( 'designer', 'designer_lingerie', $pattern );
        $old_rules[$old_pattern] = $substitution;
    }
    return $rules + $old_rules;
}
```

This will not generate a redirect - weird, I expected [the `redirect_canonical()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/canonical.php) to do this. You can do it yourself if you want, either by hooking into `redirect_canonical`, or by setting an extra flag that you check yourself.

Comment: My old post types no longer exist so would this work for me? I am not sure the benefits of this method. What would the benefit of not using Apache be? Just curiuos, Thanx

Answer (score 1):

If you change the permalinks but not the underlying structure WordPress should be able to find your posts, since the 'real' url structure is still the same. In other words if you only change the permalinks it should automatically redirect to the right location.

Comment: I actually changed the post type name. so the underlying URLS are different with the new version of my site. My original post was edited to clarify my question. Thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

WP retains the corresponding metadata regarding the original non-pretty permalink and any changes to standard permalinks. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

If you have non-pretty permalinks in post/page content or leave them hardcoded anywhere, WP will redirect those to the pretty version.

That said, if you change the URL directly in the post/page editor, you do need to redirect. One of the ways to handle that is with a plugin like [WordPress › Redirection « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)