# Prettified page URL w/ query var redirects to prettified page URL w/o query var

Tags: rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I have a page created (page ID `235`) with a page template that will need to be passed a variable. I would like to pass this variable through the URL. My first attempt was to pass this with a GET variable, and that worked just fine.

```
URL: http://example.com/sok/events/?kategori=variablehere
```

Now, I thought I'd spice this up a bit and prettify it. This is what I am aiming to achieve:

```
URL: http://example.com/sok/events/variablehere
```

The code I have been using in my attempt looks like the following:

```
function setup_filter_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%kategori%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^sok/events/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?p=235&kategori=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
```

Now, when accessing the URL above, I am redirected to `http://example.com/sok/events/` - i.e. the URL but without the query variable. Obviously, as you may guess, the query variable is not accessible inside the page.

I heard of the `redirect_canonical` function potentially causing problems with rewrite rules, so I disabled it. After having done so, accessing the above URL instead yields a 404.php request.

As you can see, I've really tried to cut back on the code to make it as simple as possible as well as using the correct API functions. I have checked the rule with [A tool to analyze rewrite rules?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) and it reports the variable as being public and accessible. I tried cutting the page down to a simple `echo $wp_query->query_vars['kategori']` but that did not output anything nor did it prevent the redirection.

I suspect the redirection is the problem here - if I could stop it, I'm confident I'd be able to grab the query variable.

This problem is similar to [URL Rewrite + Page + Custom Post Type = Unusual Redirect](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25241/url-rewrite-page-custom-post-type-unusual-redirect) and [Querystring parameter getting lost in rewrite rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26497/querystring-parameter-getting-lost-in-rewrite-rule) insofar that it is also a redirection error. However, in my case, I am not dealing with custom post types of any kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have to add `kategori` to the array of query vars:

**EDIT-** after much iteration we've arrived at a solution. the original code seemed to be working, but only with specific permalink settings, as I was mistakenly routing to a post instead of a page. rather than `p=`, it should be `pagename=`, with both the parent and child page in the path:

```
function setup_filter_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('sok/events/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=sok/events&kategori=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );  

function setup_filter_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'kategori';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'setup_filter_query_vars' );
```

Comment: I thought that was what `add_rewrite_tag` did? I tried your code (commenting out my `add_rewrite_tag`) but to no avail. It also seems the two other questions I've linked haven't been answered - this is somewhat curious!

Comment: make sure you flush rewrite rules each time you make a change. the above code pasted in a new install works here without a redirect, so maybe you have some other code or plugin interfering with the query.

Comment: are you absolutely totaly 100% sure this worked for you on a fresh install? Do you mind copy-pasting all of the code (including the code for the page template) you used into pastebin or something? I've disabled all of my plugins, even switched back to Twenty Eleven, and made sure to refresh my permalinks every time - it still redirects to the page URL without the appended query variable. I'm beginning to think this is some sort of bug, as I cannot see what is going or wrong or where it happens.

Comment: @Doggie52 - ok, I think I've figured out what may be your issue. What are your permalink settings? I can reproduce the redirect if I set permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/`. any other permalink setting works except that one. [here are the template files I'm using](http://pastebin.com/032rMsP8).

Comment: well, _events_ is a page and _sok_ is its parent page, so I am not using that particular permalink structure, no. But it somewhat resembles your proposed error-causing structure, I admit that. I'll see what happens when ridding myself of the parent page. In the meantime, let me ponder over this: does your ability to reproduce this error with a very particular permalink structure turn this into a bug?

Comment: Negative on the above -- purely query:ing the page still showed the same refresh. I'm clueless about how to solve this -- do you perhaps think it's a bug?

Comment: another thing I've noticed, if you point your rewrite to a page instead of a post it won't redirect: `'index.php?pagename=somepage&kategori=$matches[1]'`. Can't speak to whether or not this is a bug or expected behaviour.

Comment: Aah! There we go! That must be my problem - the _events_ -page is.. well.. a page! But that makes no sense, why would it not work with pages but work with posts? I'm submitting this to trac once I get time, thanks in advance for helping me troubleshoot it.

Comment: to clarify- i was originally pointing mine to a post instead of a page. if you use `pagename=events` rather than `p=235` I think it will work.

Comment: Negative -- `pagename=events` will not work. Do you get that to work?

Comment: ok, sorry, should be `pagename=sok/events&kategori=$matches[1]` since events is a child of sok. this works for me regardless of permalink setting.

Comment: You are my savior. Edit your question and I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: ok, i've edited the answer with the correct code.