# Query var removed after rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls, custom-post-type-archives

I have a WordPress blog that uses custom post types, which I'm creating using the [WCK plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/). One of which is the post type **shows**. A permalink to a specific show, then, appears as:

```
http://my-website.com/wordpress/shows/show-slug/
```

This is all done through the current functionality of WP and the WCK plugin. However, I am trying to add another "level" of detailed information to be displayed on that single show page. For this, I am using the URL query variable **item** to designate this.

So, for example, if I want to view the list of episodes for a certain show, I could visit the URL:

```
http://my-website.com/wordpress/shows/show-slug/?item=episodes
```

These "items" vary per-show and are more or less arbitrary, but I already have the logic on the single-shows.php template to determine whether or not the item provided in the URL query is a valid one for that show.

Anyway, I want to use the rewrite functionality to make the URLs a little bit nicer, with the format:

```
http://my-website.com/wordpress/shows/show-slug/episodes
```

This is where I'm running into problems. Here is my PHP script in my theme's functions.php file to register that URL query var and the rewrite rule:

```
function shows_item_tag_registration() {
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('item'); 
}

function shows_item_rule_registration($rules) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['^shows/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=shows/$matches[1]&item=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','shows_item_rule_registration' );
add_action( 'init','shows_item_tag_registration' );
```

I am not flushing the rewrite rules myself, as I do not want to lose the rules being written by the Permalinks settings in the WP Admin. Instead, as you can see, I am adding my rule to the "current list" in the **rewrite_rules_array** filter. To apply changes, I re-save the Permalinks settings in the WP admin, and that seems to be doing the trick as far as that goes.

Frustratingly, it almost works, but when I try to visit the URL with the item at the end, like so:

```
http://my-website.com/wordpress/shows/show-slug/episodes
```

It simply redirects me to:

```
http://my-website.com/wordpress/shows/show-slug/
```

And removes the item from the query altogether. I found [this Stack Exchange question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26914/prettified-page-url-w-query-var-redirects-to-prettified-page-url-w-o-query-var) that seemed pretty similar, but I was not able to resolve my issue with the answer from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are not using the correct hooks nor the correct rewrite rule. You are rewriting to `pagename`, which is for pages. You should use `name` to get posts by slug.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'cyb_add_query_vars');
function cyb_add_query_vars( $vars) {
   $vars[] = "item";
   return $vars;
}
add_action('init','cyb_add_rewrite_rules');
function cyb_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( ''^shows/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$'' , 'index.php?post_type=shows&name=$matches[1]&item=$matches[2]' , 'top' );
}
```

You can also add a endpoint and use URLs like `http://my-website.com/wordpress/shows/show-slug/item/episodes`:

```
add_action('init','cyb_add_endpoint');
function cyb_add_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'item', EP_PERMALINK );
}
```

And don't forget to flush the rewirte rules. If you don't want to code the flush, visit the permalink settings page in wp-admin area, click on save and the rewrite rules will be flushed.

Comment: Looks like that did it, thank you very much! I didn't add the endpoint because of how I wanted the final URLs to look, but your script above that did the trick.