# The website has resulted in too many redirects (redirect plugin)?

Tags: plugins

I changed the redirect URL of one page from  http://goldstarteachers.com/teachers/jobs to  http://goldstarteachers.com/teachers/teaching-jobs-china/. I set up a redirect so that the old URL lead to the new one.

I'm using the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) by John Godley

I then realised it affected a lot of other pages so I changed the URL back to the original one (http://goldstarteachers.com/teachers/jobs) and deleted the redirects I had set up.

The problem is, if I now visit http://goldstarteachers.com/teachers/jobs it comes up with an error message.

The page still exists and can be seen in the WordPress admin section as a page called "Teaching Jobs in China".

I have deleted my computers cookies and tried loading this page on another computer but it does not load.

Now each time I visite that page I get this error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop The webpage at
>   http://goldstarteachers.com/teachers/jobs/ has resulted in too many
>   redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party
>   cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server
>   configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

What could be the cause of the problem? Any suggestions to fix this?

**EDIT:**

**Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer**

[image]

**Redirection**

[image]

Comment: Install the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin (see [instructions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3608/73)) and add the listed rules to your question.

Comment: @toscho♦ OK I edited my question.

Comment: Hm, I  see now the plugin doesn't use the rewrite API, it works with its own database table instead. Have you tried to remove all rules containing `teacher` or `jobs`?

Comment: @toscho Yes, I deleted them all. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: There are still two rules with `teacher` or `jobs`. Remove those too, visit the permalinks settings page once (just to be sure), and try again.

Comment: i also face same problem on when i post new post in my blog anyone know how to fix them??

Answer (score 1):

Tools>>Redirection>>Options>> "URL Monitoring: You can have Redirection detect changes in URLs and have an automatic redirection created in a specific group."

If this option is set to "Monitor", you will get loops and strange redirections if you change a page or posts' URL with a redirect and then change them back to the original URL.

Comment: I deleted all redirections and changed the options to "Don't Monitor" but still getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great little tool, but you should know that it automatically creates the redirects when you change the name of a post or page's url. If you go ahead and manually add them in, it will create an error of too many redirects.

I had this problem yesterday and today, and after a half of a day reading several blog/forum posts about this subject I recalled someone stating that the too many redirects effects the code in the htaccess file of your root directory. I had a recent back of my blog and just uploaded it to overwrite the current file, and voila! - it was fixed! I have a complete write up about how to go about doing this for those who do not know where to find the file, or what tools to use to do so at http://thetaseo.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/wordpress-too-many-redirects/ (It's just my personal diary that I seldom write it, but I hope it helps someone.)

I wouldn't want anyone to go through what I just did! I assume other people are scouring the Internet to find the answer as well. So, I'm going back to all of the posts I read and posting this. Good luck!

Comment: Please post a summary an relevant code into your answer so that the answer stays meaningful if something happens to that link.