# Permalinks for custom taxonomy stopped to work

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm not sure when this happened, I just noticed it. I have custom taxonomies and post types.

For the longest time I was able to go to `domain.com/taxonomy/term` and it would display the posts related. Now it's not.

I'm still able to access it by `domain.com/?taxonomy=taxonomyhere&term=termhere`

The last time I remember this working I was on Apache but have recently moved over to nginx. I thought I tested a while ago and it and it was working though.

Comment: I'm assuming you already visited `Settings > Permalinks`?

Comment: @developdaly I should know better to just go there and click save to clear out whatever it stored but I didn't. Doing so just now fixed the issue, thanks. Why would that break though, anything I might have done to break it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a plugin changes WordPress' internal rewrite rules during an update, an installation or deactivation. If the plugin's update happens to run *after* your taxonomy registration it may just wipe out the custom rules for the taxonomy.

To inspect the currently active rewrite rules use the [plugin Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/). See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3608/73) for details.

To refresh the rewrite rules visit the permalink settings page once.