# Custom Rewrite Problem

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm creating some custom rewrites using the code below.  Everything works fine, as far as urls such as this:

example.com/reviews/showname

Tells my theme to use the special archive page and passes the parameters I need.  The problem I run into is with pagination. Wordpress generates the links properly:

example.com/reviews/showname/page/2/

but the result is a page not found.  My first thought was to add a second rewrite:

```
 'reviews/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)' =>  'index.php?reviews=1&showarchive=1&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&pgd=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&pgn=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
```

So that I could capture the 'page' and the page number and use those to code an offset into the query and set the paged query var, but I find when I add this it cancels out the other so that:

example.com/reviews/showname

Now returns page not found but

example.com/reviews/showname/page/1/

Works.  For SEO purposes I'd like to keep the

example.com/reviews/showname

Style url without /page/1 — is there any way to get the rewrites working for both conditions?

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'eparchive_queryvars' );

function eparchive_queryvars( $qvars )
{
  $qvars[] = 'showarchive';
  $qvars[] = 'reviews';
  $qvars[] = 'pgd';
  $qvars[] = 'pgn';
  return $qvars;
}    

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_add_rewrite_rules');

    function custom_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
    {
      $new_rules = array( 

         'reviews/(.+)' =>  'index.php?reviews=1&showarchive=1&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
         );
      $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these rules:

```
reviews/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$
reviews/([^/]+)/?$
```

It's informative to check out the active rewrite rules with:

```
function show_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    if(is_admin()) echo "<pre>".print_r($rules,true)."</pre>";
    return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','show_rewrite_rules');
```

and then visit `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`.

There exists also some good plugins for analysing the rewrite rules, for example the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules).

Comment: Thanks Birgire!  I guess it was a matter of using the right example.