# how rewrite is working in wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting

I have installed a plugin called marketpress. 
And it have a url as `http://www.mydomain.com/store/shopping-cart/shipping/` 
Now i just want to know which php page it refers to.

In **my db** and found there is a row in **wp_options** table with the key **rewrite_rules** and it have

```
[store/shopping-cart/?$] => index.php?pagename=cart
[store/shopping-cart/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?pagename=cart&checkoutstep=$matches[1]
```

so as per my url the link will be as like `index.php?pagename=cart&checkoutstep=shipping`

If the url is like this **which php page the wordpress will look for?**

Basically i am a cakephp developer. So all i think is for a controller and action something like that.

Can someone explain me how can i find the how the wordpress will refer tot he dependent php page base on the url? **Which page i should refer if ?pagename=cart is passed is passed**

My english may poor. But i hope you guys understand what i am trying to ask :\

Comment: This is rather broad. Have you read [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to the WordPress Rewrite API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api)?

Answer (score 0):

You can best analyse the URL rewrites with the URL Rewrite Analyser which has been developed by Jan Fabry, see [the following answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) for more information.

Furthermore you can change the structure of the permalinks under the Options --> Permalinks of the WordPress admin section.