# How to prevent redirection to max 2147483647 for larger values of the page query variable?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I've got an id which is `10101000003163`

I set it to my href as `"technical/10101000003163/"`

but WordPress redirects me to `"technical/2147483647/"`

How can I stop WordPress from doing that?

My rewrite rule is

```
function rewrite_technical() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^technical/([0-9])/?', 'technical/?pid=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_technical');
```

Comment: What is that id?

Comment: very unlikely, some other part of your code is probably doing that

Comment: @bravokeyl thats the product id we got in our system, its not just by incrementing, the first 5 digit is the origin code.. etc etc so I cannot modify it

Comment: @MarkKaplun when I remove the rewrite and I go for `technical/?pid=10101000003163` its working.

Comment: What happens if you move the rule to top instead of bottom? (still wordpress to not usually redirect to random addresses)

Comment: 2147483647 is max value for int, what I don't know is why wordpress converting it to int upon reading it. its url. its has been an issue, but no one really provides a solution

Comment: Do you have the Nextgen Gallery plugin installed? This also uses the pid tag. There may be some interference.

Comment: @cjbj no im not using any plugins

Comment: And you have flushed the rewrite rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Why Part

If we have a page called `technical` and try to load:

```
example.tld/technical/99999999999999999999
```

then the `99999999999999999999` part is treated as a `page` query variable with the value of `2147483647`.

The reason is this rewrite rule for pages:

[image: rewrite rules]

according to the handy [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608) by Jan Fabry.

[This part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/15ce1ec9393fb52fd61c38edb80dd6aa97dc2355/wp-includes/query.php#L2599-2602) of the `WP_Query::get_posts()`:

```
if ( isset($q['page']) ) {
    $q['page'] = trim($q['page'], '/');
    $q['page'] = absint($q['page']);
}
```

is responsible for the integer conversion, i.e.

```
absint( '99999999999999999999' ) =  2147483647
```

This is actually the [same as](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/):

```
abs( intval( '99999999999999999999' ) )
```

I tested also:

```
intval( 99999999999999999999 )
```

but that just gives 0.

I checked the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) on [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) that says:

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum
>   signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on
>   such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The
>   maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is
>   9223372036854775807.
>
> Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the
>   leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of integer casting
>   apply.

Finally the *canonical redirect* kicks in and redirects to:

```
example.tld/technical/2147483647/
```

Your current rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^technical/([0-9])/?', 
    'technical/?pid=$matches[1]', 
    'bottom'
);
```

seems to be wrong. It's e.g. missing the `index.php` part and only supports a single digit.

### Workaround

Try e.g. <strike>(untested)</strike>:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^technical/([0-9]+)/?', 
    'index.php?pagename=technical&wpseid=$matches[1]', 
    'top' 
);

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $qv )
{
    $qv[] = 'wpseid';
    return $qv;
} );
```

where I changed `pid` to `wpseid` to avoid possible name collisions.

Now you should be able to use `$wpseid = get_query_var( 'wpseid' );` to retrieve it unmodified.

Note that you will most likely loose the possibility of *content pagination* for that page.

... or just switch to a 64 bit system where:

```
9223372036854775807 > 10101000003163
```

and just use a combination of `is_page( 'technical' )` and  `get_query_var( 'page' )` but that sounds like be a messy solution, so I wouldn't really recommend it  ;-)